# Bitwise operator in pseudo-code

Tags: pseudocode

I am translating a C++ program into pseudo-code using the `algorithmicx` package.

Do you know how I can represent the C bitwise operator like the shifts (<< and >>) ?

Until now I used power of 2 but it's not very convenient.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "I used power of 2"?

Comment: @Hendrik: Apparently `x \cdot 2^n` and `x / 2^n`, where `n` is the shift amount.

Comment: @Andrey: Thanks, now I get it - in pseudo-code that's not too bad.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Notice that << behaves differently than power when running out of bits.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pseudocode has a different purpose compared to the actual programs. It should convey ideas, not implementation, and as such should be as close to the natural language as possible. Therefore I think it's not good to introduce programming language-specific syntax in the algorithm listing.

I suggest one of these options:

- continue using `algorithmicx` and select a human-readable name for the operation: `\State $x \gets \Call{ShiftLeft}{x, 3}$`;
- use the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package and typeset the actual C++ program with comments.

Comment: Ok I will use the Call (I didn't know it).

Answer (score 27):

I advise against Andrey’s solution. He is right that in general pseudocode should be independent of a specific machine or language.

But this breaks down with bit operations. Bit operations *do* suggest a specific underlying architecture, and the bit operators follow an established nomenclature.

You don’t make the code more readable by ignoring this convention – in fact, you do the opposite.

I have the following commands defined in my thesis template:

```
\newcommand*\BitAnd{\mathbin{\&}}
\newcommand*\BitOr{\mathbin{|}}
\newcommand*\ShiftLeft{\ll}
\newcommand*\ShiftRight{\gg}
\newcommand*\BitNeg{\ensuremath{\mathord{\sim}}}
```

(The command names follow the naming convention of the `algorithmicx` package which I can recommend for typesetting algorithms.)

That said, you should second-guess your reason for using bit operations in the first place – often they are only used to achieve specific optimisations, in which case they have no place in a pseudo-code. On the other hand, sometimes (and it sounds as if this may be the case for you) they have a legitimate purpose.

Comment: I agree that your point is valid. A yet better approach would be to use the C-style notation and add a list of operators and their meanings somewhere in the beginning of the document. This eliminates any possible confusion.

Comment: How about `\BitXor`? I tried `\newcommand{\BitXor}{\mathrel{\^}}` and it's giving me problems (in MathJax, maybe something strange there, but the other commands worked (non-starred)
)

Comment: @NickT See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77646/42.

Comment: It seems [`\mathbin` is more appropriate than `\mathrel`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38982/185783).

Answer (score 12):

For symbols, you can use `\ll` and `\gg` for shifting, and `\lll`, `\ggg` for rotating.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

$a\land b$, $a\lor b$, $\lnot a$, $a\oplus b$

$a\ll b$, $a\gg b$, $a\lll b$, $a\ggg b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also define some functions:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\shl{shl}% shift left
\DeclareMathOperator\shr{shr}% shift right
\DeclareMathOperator\rol{rol}% rotate left
\DeclareMathOperator\ror{ror}% rotate right
```

and use `$\shl(a,n)$` etc. in the algorithm.

Comment: \ll and \gg means more "very lower" and "very greater" rather than bit level shift.

Comment: @Ubiquité: Yes, I know that. But they are actully used in some algorithm descriptions, especially in figures. For example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1

Comment: Plus, in the 'normal' representation of the programming construct, they are not, I think, kerned.

Comment: @Brent But they look better when kerned. Pretty-printed pseudo-code can take some freedom with operators. Many authors do this and in some cases (Haskell and ML come to mind) this is actually encouraged and something of a standard.

Comment: @Konrad: Knuth's WEB comes to mind too. `weave tex.web` and then run `pdftex tex`.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `\verb` command, e. g.

```
\verb|<<|
```

and

```
\verb|>>|
```

if you need to have those operators displayed exactly as they would be typed in a program, and do not want to use other packages for that.

Answer (score 4):

In mathematics `\ll` is often used for "much less than" and using both in one document creates a need to distinguish this symbol from the bit shift operator.

My suggestion is to combine the answers of Konrad and PointedEars thusly:

```
\DeclareMathOperator\ShiftLeft{\texttt{<<}}% shift left
```

The \verb command is overpowered for this purpose and has some restrictions which make it harder to work with. I use `\texttt{<<}` instead, as it may more easily be included into macros. It's also a good idea to make a macro out of whatever you settle on, so in the future you only have to change it in one place if you change your mind.