# What is the difference between \mathbin vs. \mathrel?

Tags: math-mode

These seem to be very similar as they both separate two operands.
When would one be used over the other?
Is there any difference in the math spacing surrounding them?

How would the spacing in these relate to to the spacing produced by `\mathop`?

Comment: Related Question: [What's the right space to right the alignment of a right aligned align environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81752/whats-the-right-space-to-right-the-alignment-of-a-right-aligned-align-environme#comment174745_81752).

Answer (score 133, accepted):

From the name, `\mathbin` modifies the spacing around something so that it adheres to that of a binary *operator*, while `\mathrel` modifies the spacing to denote that of a binary *relation*. Here is an elementary approach at showcasing the difference:

[image: tables]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{clc}
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Relations} \\[5pt]
  \LaTeX & Typeset & width \\ \hline
  \verb|$x=x$| & $x=x$ & \setbox0=\hbox{$x=x$} \the\wd0 \\
  \verb|$x\mathbin{=}x$| & $x\mathbin{=}x$ & \setbox0=\hbox{$x\mathbin{=}x$} \the\wd0 \\
  \verb|$x\mathrel{=}x$| & $x\mathrel{=}x$ & \setbox0=\hbox{$x\mathrel{=}x$} \the\wd0 \\[10pt]
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Binary operators} \\[5pt]
  \LaTeX & Typeset & width \\ \hline
  \verb|$x+x$| & $x+x$ & \setbox0=\hbox{$x+x$} \the\wd0 \\
  \verb|$x\mathbin{+}x$| & $x\mathbin{+}x$ & \setbox0=\hbox{$x\mathbin{+}x$} \the\wd0 \\
  \verb|$x\mathrel{+}x$| & $x\mathrel{+}x$ & \setbox0=\hbox{$x\mathrel{+}x$} \the\wd0
\end{tabular}
\end{document}​
```

Note the spacing around `+` matching that of `\mathbin`, while the spacing around `=` matches that of `\mathrel`.

From the TeXBook (**Chapter 17: More about Math**, p 154-):

> Every math character is given an identifying code number between 0 and
>   4095, obtained by adding 256 times the family number to the position
>   number. This is easily expressed in hexadecimal notation, using one
>   hexadecimal digit for the family and two for the character; for
>   example, `\hex{24A}` stands for character `\hex{4A}` in family 2. Each
>   character is also assigned to one of eight classes, numbered 0 to 7,
>   as follows:
>
> Class 0: Ordinary (eg., `/`)
>   Class 1: Large operator (eg., `\sum`)
>   Class 2: Binary operation (eg., `+`)
>   Class 3: Relation (eg., `=`)
>   Class 4: Opening (eg., `(`)
>   Class 5: Closing (eg., `)`)
>   Class 6: Punctuation (eg., `,`)
>   Class 7: Variable family (eg., `x`)
>
> Classes 0 to 6 tell what "part of speech" the character belongs to, in
>   math-printing language; class 7 is a special case [...]. The class
>   number is multiplied by 4096 and added to the character number, and
>   this is the same as making it the leading digit of a four-digit
>   hexadecimal number.
>   ...
>   TeX associates classes with subformulas as well as with individual
>   characters. Thus, for example, you can treat a complex construction as
>   if it were a binary operation or a relation, etc., if you want to. The
>   commands `\mathord`, `\mathop`, `\mathbin`, `\mathrel`, `\mathopen`,
>   `\mathclose`, and `\mathpunct` are used for this purpose; each of them
>   is followed either by a single character or by a subformula in braces.
>   For example, `\mathopen\mathchar"1234` is equivalent to
>   `\mathchar"4234`, because `\mathopen` forces class 4 (opening). In the
>   formula `$G\mathbin:H$`, the colon is treated as a binary operation.
>   ...
>   There's also an eighth classification, `\mathinner`, which is not
>   normally used for individual symbols; fractions and `\left...\right`
>   constructions are treated as "inner" subformulas, which means that
>   they will be surrounded by additional space in certain circumstances.
>   All other subformulas are generally treated as ordinary symbols,
>   whether they are formed by `\overline` or `\hbox` or `\vcenter` or by
>   simply being enclosed in braces. Thus, `\mathord` isn't really a
>   necessary part of the TeX language; instead of typing
>   `$1\mathord,234$` you can get the same effect from `$1{,}234$`.

Comment: Most lists I have seen does not include class 7, but treats alphanumeric characters as ordinary. Why is it different here?

Comment: @Gaussler: Class 7 indeed behaves the same as class 0 with regards to spacing. The difference is in what font the character is taken from.

Answer (score 64):

There are three main differences between `\mathrel` and `\mathbin`:

**1.** For optimal readability of math formulas, the more important elements must receive more space. That's why `\mathrel` (for math relations like `=`, `<`, `>`, etc.) receives a thick space (5/18th of an em) while `\mathbin` (for math binary operators like `+`, `-`, `\oplus`, etc.) receives a medium space (4/18th of an em). The difference is subtle, but enhances reading of formulas.

**2.** `\mathbin` and `\mathrel` behave differently relative to shrinking or stretching. When TeX does not have enough space available on a given line, it will contract a `\mathbin` space while it will never do so for a `\mathrel` space. When TeX has too much space available on a given line, it will stretch both. Here are the values used (1mu = 1/18th em):

```
\medmuskip = 4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
\thickmuskip = 5mu plus 5mu
```

Here's an example of both situations:

[image: examples of stretching and shrinking situations]

As you can see, in a shrinking situation, `+` has no space around it, but in stretching situations, `=` can extend much more than `+` (10/18th em vs 6/18th em).

**3.** Finally, `\mathbin` and `\mathrel` behave differently in different contexts. For example, `$A = -B$` works as expected (no space between `-` and `B`) but `$A = \mathrel{-}B$` would not:

[image: example of bad spacing if mathrel is used instead of mathbin]

This is only one example of what can go wrong with the spacing if the type of the symbol is incorrect.

**Comparison to `\mathop`:** contrary to `\mathbin` and `\mathrel`, `\mathop` is for things like `\sum`,  `\cos`, `\ln` etc. and only inserts a thin space (3/18th em, no shrinking or stretching) and, just as `\mathbin` and `\mathrel`, has special spacing rules to make it spaced correctly in most context.

Comment: from what I recall, the spacing around `\mathbin` and `\mathrel` is "symmetric" in that it is the same before and after the symbol, while `\mathop` isn't: it puts things closer to the symbol on the right. Is that correct?

Comment: The spacing around symbols depends on the objects which are around; for example between a mathop and an opening there's no space (compare `\log x` and `\log(xy)`.