# Differences between \stackrel and \stackbin

Tags: math-mode

What are the differences between `\stackrel` and `\stackbin`? In what situations is it better to use one or the other?

Comment: Effectively, this boils down to the question related to `\mathbin` and `\mathrel` which can be found in [what is the difference between `mathbin` vs. `mathrel`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38982/what-is-the-difference-between-mathbin-vs-mathrel)

Comment: Which do I use if I just want to stack text and do not want added spacing to separate math from text?

Comment: @Village: If you want to remove any text influence from your `\stackrel` (or `\stackbin`) choice, then you can use `\usepackage{amsmath,stackrel}$a\stackrel{\text{\makebox[0pt]{abc}}}{=}b$`. This typesets `abc` in text mode in the appropriate font size without any width, and would therefore not influence math spacing. `\stackrel` and `\stackbin` typically only have narrow entries on top of/below them. Is this what you might be after?

Comment: Yes, I just want three layers of stacked and centered text, without modifying any of the spacing. Would it be better if I used some other way to position the text in three levels?

Comment: @Village: You could use any number of means. For example, typeset things in an `array` or `tabular` that is vertically centered, or use `\stackrel`. Either way, this seems to be a departure from your current question which relates specifically to `\stackrel` and `\stackbin`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Without the `stackrel` package, `\stackrel` is defined in [`ltxmath.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/ltmath.dtx) as

```
\def\stackrel#1#2{\mathrel{\mathop{#2}\limits^{#1}}}
```

which typesets a relational operator with a top limit (effectively placing it on top). Heiko Oberdiek's [`stackrel` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/stackrel) is said to provide an

> Enhancement to the `\stackrel` command.

This "enhancement" provides an optional argument to `\stackrel` for placing something below the relational operator (using a similar process as the original `\stackrel`). Additionally, it provides a counterpart for binary relations called `\stackbin`. The difference between the two (or when to use which one) is contained within the post [What is the difference between `\mathbin` vs. `\mathrel`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38982/5764) Here is a similar take on the use of `stackrel`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stackrel}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{clc}
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Relations} \\[5pt]
  \LaTeX & Typeset & width \\
  \hline
  \verb|$x=x$| & $x=x$ & \setbox0=\hbox{$x=x$} \the\wd0 \\
  \verb|$x\stackbin[c]{a}{=}x$| & $x\stackbin[c]{a}{=}x$ & 
    \setbox0=\hbox{$x\stackbin[c]{a}{=}x$} \the\wd0 \\
  \verb|$x\stackrel[c]{a}{=}x$| & $x\stackrel[c]{a}{=}x$ & 
    \setbox0=\hbox{$x\stackrel[c]{a}{=}x$} \the\wd0 \\[10pt]
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Binary operators} \\[5pt]
  \LaTeX & Typeset & width \\
  \hline
  \verb|$x+x$| & $x+x$ & \setbox0=\hbox{$x+x$} \the\wd0 \\
  \verb|$x\stackbin[c]{a}{+}x$| & $x\stackbin[c]{a}{+}x$ & 
    \setbox0=\hbox{$x\stackbin[c]{a}{+}x$} \the\wd0 \\
  \verb|$x\stackrel[c]{a}{+}x$| & $x\stackrel[c]{a}{+}x$ & 
    \setbox0=\hbox{$x\stackrel[c]{a}{+}x$} \the\wd0
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note the equivalent spacing using `\stackrel` with `=`, while similar spacing is returned using `\stackbin` and `+`. In essence, use `\stackrel` for relational operators, and `\stackbin` for binary operators.

Comment: why do you use `$x=x$ & \setbox0=\hbox{$x=x$} \the\wd0` instead of `\setbox0=\hbox{$x=x$} \usebox0 & \the\wd0` ?

Comment: @user2987828: No particular reason. The storing to a box and measuring occurs in the same cell.

Answer (score 127):

Don't use `\stackrel` or `\stackbin`, they are obsolete. Use instead `\underset` and `\overset` from amsmath as they automatically space things correctly (whether it's a binary relation or a binary operator):

[image: result of the code below]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$f(x) \overset{\text{def}}{=} x \ln(1+x)$

$f(x) \underset{x \to 0}{=} x^2 + o(x^2)$

$A \underset{\text{below}}{\overset{\text{above}}{+}} C$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a reference which clearly shows that and why \stack* is obsolete?

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r: you're not going to find a better reason than the one I gave in my post (manual spacing vs automatic spacing). I should also have mentioned `\overunderset` that puts something both above and below the symbol (and would have simplified my third example).

Answer (score 13):

I personally prefer using `\mathop`, because it's simpler. Instead of using nested under/oversets, you could simply write:

```
$A \mathop{+}_{\text{below}}^{\text{above}} C$
```

Comment: That works if you wrap it in \displaystyle{} ; otherwise (inline mode) it behaves like \Sum etc. and puts the text on the right as superscript / subscript.

Comment: You can use $A \mathop{+}\limits_{\text{below}}^{\text{above}} C$ in inline mode.