# How do I put text over symbols?

Tags: syntax

This is difficult for me to explain, but how do I put words over a symbol? For instance, I want to add words over an equal sign. Anyone know the command/syntax for that?

Also adding `^` doesn't cut it..., I want the text to appear ON TOP.

Comment: What text do you want above the equal sign?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can use a combination of `\stackrel` and `\mathclap` (from the `mathtools` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\myeq{\stackrel{\mathclap{\normalfont\mbox{def}}}{=}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a &\myeq b \\
  &=c \\
  &= d.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If using `mathtools` is not an option, you can use a `\makebox` of width `0pt`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\myeq{\mathrel{\stackrel{\makebox[0pt]{\mbox{\normalfont\tiny def}}}{=}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a &\myeq b \\
  &=c \\
  &= d.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Even better, if `amsmath` has been loaded, is to use `\overset` instead of `\stackrel`; a little example using `\tiny\sffamily` for "def" :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\myeq{\mathrel{\overset{\makebox[0pt]{\mbox{\normalfont\tiny\sffamily def}}}{=}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a &\myeq b \\
  &=c \\
  &= d.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Inside the argument for `\mbox` one can use some of the font modifiers, as I did in my second and third examples.

Particularly, I don't like this kind of notation (it's not really necessary); you should consider if you really need the text above the equal sign.

Comment: Wouldn't be `\mbox` better than `\text` in this case, so that the `def` is still upshape even e.g. in theorem?

Comment: @tohecz -- if upshape is always desired, then the expression (as in this case) is probably an operator name, so that approach would be better.

Comment: @tohecz yes; I updated my answer. Thanks you.

Comment: I'd prefer `\overset` to `\stackrel`; instead of `\mbox` I'd use `\mathrm` or `\textnormal`.

Comment: @egreg; right; I've added an example with `\overset`; thank you. I kept the `\mbox` since I wanted to illustrate changes to the font for the text (which the OP seems to want to apply according to a comment to the other answer).

Comment: You should issue `\normalfont` inside the `\mbox` anyway, or "def" would inherit the font attributes which are current outside the formula (it may be italics in a theorem statement, for instance).

Comment: @egreg oh, you're right. Added. Thanks, again.

Comment: I learned from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130510/write-text-correctly-in-equations that we can use \operatorname{def} to have "def" with proper text font withing a theorem environment. Here "def" feels like an operator anyway, just like cos and sin.

Comment: @verdelite I would use \textnormal rather than \operatorname. "def" is more of a piece of descriptive text than an *operator* which is inherently a math object. Sine is, for example, a function. "Define" is by no means a math object.

Answer (score 176):

```
$\stackrel{sometext}{=}$
```

if  `sometext` is not intended to be in *math mode* then write `\text{sometext}` within. (`\text` is available in `amsmath` package)

```
$\stackrel{\text{sometext}}{=}$
```

blessings

Comment: Is it possible to change the size and fonts of the text? I tried {\small sometext|, but it didn't work. Also the syntax isn't working very well in \begin{align}...\end{align} environment

Comment: @jak: Please include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that shows your current usage and highlight clearly what you want or need changed. Do so via an [edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/74125/edit) to your post.

Comment: @jak: You can't use `\small` in mathmode. Have a look at **Gonzalo**'s answer, he successfully uses `\tiny` there...

Comment: @Hawk now with my edit, by using the command `\text` inside, you can use any text command you want ;)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39230/75621 suggests to use `\underset` instead of `\stackrel`, because the former is "obsolete".

Answer (score 96):

```
$\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}$
```

`\overset` is available in `amsmath` package.

Good luck.

Comment: And with the corresponding `\underset` option, this the simplest answer.

Comment: By far the most simple way.

Answer (score 6):

All answers here suppose that you are using LaTeX (??). If it is not true then there is standard plain TeX macro `\buildrel` for doing this. The syntax is `\buildrel (what above) \over (relation)`

```
$a \buildrel \rm def \over = b$
\bye
```