# Add a comment on top of "equal" and "approximate" symbols

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I was wondering whether it is possible to add some comment on top 
of the `\approx` symbol in a similar way that the command `\xrightarrow{text}` produces an arrow with text over it.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74125/15925

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `\stackrel{}{}` for this:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\approxtext}[1]{\ensuremath{\stackrel{\text{#1}}{\approx}}}
\begin{document}
    $\displaystyle
        A \stackrel{\text{text}}{\approx} B
    $, 
    $\displaystyle
        A \approxtext{test} B
    $
\end{document}
```

Or a small wrapper: `\newcommand{\approxtext}[1]{\ensuremath{\stackrel{\text{#1}}{\approx}}}`. Result:

[image]

Comment: The text above the symbol should probably treated as text, not as math. What's the purpose of the additional braces?

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation
However, I don't see the difference between the different approaches?
I found that I can also accommodate math in the text above by the usual prescription `$mathtext$`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\stackrel{a=b}{\approx}` or if it is real text `\stackrel{\text{your text}}{\approx}` if your text is not too long. The `\approx` symbol is rather small, so I wouldn't add too much on top to keep your equations readable.

Comment: That's working perfect!
Thanks for the quickness!
Just to know, which package does it comes from this? ams math?

Comment: @pablo: Actually, you don't even need `amsmath` for this. But `amsmath` has two more commands: `\overset` and `\underset`. The former does basically the same as `\stackrel`

Comment: What is the text is long? What command is to be used then?

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned `\stackrel` can be used for it. I'd just recommend adding `\scriptscriptstyle` or, say, `\tiny` if it is just text, plus `\smash`. Otherwise one often ends up having a combined symbol that mess with the line spacing if used in the text.

```
\newcommand\defeq{\stackrel{\smash{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{def}}}{=}}
```

Small size to reduce the height
`\smash` to remove the height completely (the small size then help us not to overlap too much with the line above)