# add (a little bit long) comment on the equal sign?

Tags: math-mode, syntax, stacking-symbols

There are posts here explained how to [Add a comment on top of "equal" and "approximate" symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102604/add-a-comment-on-top-of-equal-and-approximate-symbols) , the idea is to use `\stackrel{text}{=}`, however, if the text is a bit long, for example I'd like to right

```
LHS\stackrel{t=x^n}{=}RHS
```

then the text over the equal symbol is a bit too long.

How could I make it more pretty?

Comment: You could always try `turnstile` with null verticals. `\turnstile{n}{d}{}{t=x^n}{n}`, for example. (The package automatically adjusts the horizontal lines to the size of whatever is placed over and/or under them.)

Comment: The best thing to do here is *not* to do that; surely there's a better way to indicate what you want to express than overloading the equality symbol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prettiest of all ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  y \stackrel{t=x^n}{=\joinrel=\joinrel=} x
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Less is sometimes more. Consider this merely a suggestion:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
It is obvious that
\[
  LHS \stackrel{*}{=} RHS
\]
where $\stackrel{*}{=}$ denotes an equality based on the fact that $t = x^n\!$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I'll adopt your approach however take @JPi 's reply as the (literal) answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `stackengine` package has a parameter `\def\useanchorwidth{}` that when set to `T`, ignores the stacked-on or -under content when determining the width of the stack.  The optional argument provides the stacking gap.  A `{}={}` had to be used to get the stacked equal sign to act as a math relation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
$LHS\stackunder[1pt]{{}={}}{\scriptstyle t=x^n}RHS$\par\medskip
$y\stackon[4pt]{{}={}}{\scriptscriptstyle blah-blah}A x^2 +Bx +c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat similar to [Werner's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193691/15874) but with the additional use of `\mathclap` and `\smash`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*\Ref[2]{\stackrel{\mathclap{\scriptscriptstyle\smash{(#1)}}}{#2}}
\newcommand*\RefEq[1]{\ensuremath{(#1)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  A \Ref{\triangle}{=} B
\end{equation}
From \RefEq{\triangle} we see that $A = B$.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

With aligned equal signs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\Huge
$LHS\,\stackrel{\mathllap{t}=\mathrlap{x^n}}{=}\,RHS$

\end{document}
```

[image]