# Write 'text' **correctly** in equations

Tags: math-mode, equations

Although many have attempted to explain the difference among `\mathrm`, `\textrm`, `\textnormal` and `\text` (and others?), I found them misleading.

See for example the LaTeX's Wiki `\mathrm` explanation
[image]

Why is it wrong? Let's try all of them within an `article` and a `beamer` and you'll see the difference and, therefore, error.

#### `equation.tex`

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int_1^9\! \cos{x} \,\mathrm{d}x & & \textrm{this is textrm}\
  \sum_1^9 y                       & & \textsf{this is textsf}\
  \prod_1^9 z                      & & \textnormal{this is textnormal}\
  \bigcup_1^9 w                    & & \text{and this is just text}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

#### `article.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
  \input {equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And until here everything looks fine...

#### `beamer.tex`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \input{equation}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here we can clearly see that `\mathrm` does not behave as expected, i.e. does not provide a *function* aspect to the *d*. Does anyone know what am I supposed to use here instead? Just `\text`?? o.O

Moreover, I cannot see any difference between `\textnormal` and `\text`.

Finally, `\textrm` looks useless..

Comment: `\text` picks up any setting outside of math mode. Issue `\itshape` before `\input` to see (also affects `\textrm`).

Comment: You need to watch it here: `beamer`'s font set up is rather odd and should not at all be taken as giving 'guidance' on normal input for LaTeX. (I can't do much about that at this point.)

Comment: I think you have to use `\mathsf`

Comment: "`\mathrm` does not behave as expected..." To me the expected result of `\mathrm` is upright roman font. Also "`\textrm` looks useless" : why so? Your beamer example shows that it allows you to typeset upright roman font, even when the environment (in this case, the `beamer` class) tries to enforce sans serif fonts. As I understand it, the wikibook mistakes `\mathrm` (roman font) for `\textnormal` (upright font).

Comment: The *expected* behave for `\mathrm` was to reproduce the font type of *cosine* function shown above. So, have undefined functions to be enclosed in a `\textnormal` environment? Is this the *common practice*? And what about `\text`? Is it used for normal text?

Comment: how about \mbox ? I think it was an old command but what difference between it and \textnormal?

Comment: The `\textrm` command exists to switch to the default serif font without changing any other formatting. It works in math mode, but wasn’t created for this. It might have some use for switching to bold serif symbols in a bold sans-serif title, however.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You do not say what you expect `\mathrm` to do however it switches to the roman font font specified by the math version in use, which is what your images show.

You will see the difference between `\text` (which switches to the current text font) and `\textnormal` (which switches to the document default font) if you test it at a point where the current text font is not the default.

`\math....` commands are math mode commands which switch the font used for letters but the content is processed in math mode.  `\text...` commands are text mode commands which process their content in text mode, they are also allowed in math but process the commands in an hbox (by default) or if `amsmath` is loaded they use `\text` internally so that they switch to smaller sizes in subscripts etc, however the setting is still in an hbox, so that the content is processed as text rather than math.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


abcdef
$\text{abcdef} + \textrm{abcdef} + \textnormal{abcdef} + \mathrm{abcdef}$

{\sffamily
abcdef
$\text{abcdef} + \textrm{abcdef} + \textnormal{abcdef} + \mathrm{abcdef}$
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

When defining operators you should really use `\DeclareMathOperator` and not directly use font commands at all, then it works as you wish in beamer, giving sans serif. If you have existing  expressions using `\mathrm` and you want `\mathrm` to behave like `\mathsf` in beamer` you can redefine it as shown in the second expression below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator\mycos{cos}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
 $
    \cos 1 
    \mathop{\mathrm{cos}} 2
    \mycos 3
    \operatorname{cos}4
    \mathop{\mathsf{cos}}
$

\let\mathrm\mathsf

 $
    \cos 1 
    \mathop{\mathrm{cos}} 2
    \mycos 3
    \operatorname{cos}4
    \mathop{\mathsf{cos}}
$

  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A marvelous answer.  I've often wondered myself.

Comment: To me, the *expected outcome* was to reproduce the font setting of a function (see the cosine example above). So, what shall I do to write my custom function (without defining it)? Anyway, I think I am still doubtful.. Let me rephrase my question: "How shall I write functions and how shall I write text in my formulas?". At the moment I am using `\text` for both *functions* and *explanations*. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Actually, for *functions* I saw someone uses `\rm` but it does not work "as expected" with beamer.

Comment: @Atcold `\rm` is a deprecated command since we introduced latex2e back in 1993 by default it isn't defined at al in latex, classes can give it compatibility (with latex 2.09) definitions if they wish. I updated the answer with various `cos` definitions working in beamer.

Comment: Ok, prefixing that my question was not `beamer` related, the answer to how to use *text* in a formula is by using `\DeclareMathOperator` for functions (even if used just once) and `\text` for the rest. Is this right? Moreover, `\DeclareMathOperator` will introduce a space even for the case of the *d*, differential operator in an integral.

Comment: @Atcold you can use `\operatorname` as above for -one-off finctions for which you don't want to define a command. normally I'd use `\mathrm` for things like `d` or `e` but your beamer-specific issue was that you wanted to use `\mathsf` so in that case I'd probably do `\let\mathrm\mathsf` Only use `\text` if you want to drop back out to the outer context so in a theorem set slanted you get slanted so usually only for natural language text not any kind of identifier in the math, which usually requires a consistent font.

Answer (score 5):

*Copied from my answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394240/75284*

David's answer explains it well, but what I found lacking there is code that shows distinctly what each command does versus the others. So I constructed the following example with a Times clone for text mode and default Computer Modern for math. Addionally text mode gets changed to sans-serif italic to show all the changes inside these commands:

- `\text` just uses the text mode from "outside" with all the formatting.
- `\textup` is similar, only upright.
- `\textnormal` sets its content back to the normal document font without any other formatting.
- `\textrm` keeps all the text formatting, it only resets the font family.
- `\mathrm` behaves differently, I think of it as upright math mode, which is shown in my example text with the minus sign, gobbled space and square root without the compiler complaining about switching into math mode—it already is.

Depending on how much formatting you want to keep, one of these is the best choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \text
\usepackage{newtxtext} % Times-like font
\obeylines % automatic linebreaks
\begin{document}

default textmode
\sffamily\itshape
current textmode
\(\text{text}\)
\(\textup{textup}\)
\(\textnormal{textnormal}\)
\(\textrm{textrm}\)
\(\mathrm{m ath rm-\sqrt{f}}\)

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]