# How to force a math font regardless of any other factors?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, xetex

I am using Charter for math (`mathdesign` package) and Bitstream Vera for body text (through XeLaTeX's `fontspec` package. However, when using things like `\text{}` in math mode, the text still appears in the Vera font. It's hard to explain without a visual, so here is one now:

```
$$\Delta v = v_\text{exhaust} \ln \frac{m_\text{initial}}{m_\text{final}}$$
```

Which returns the following image:

[image: the Tsiolkovsky Rocket Equation]

I would like to know how I can make the words 'exhaust', 'initial', and 'final' use the Charter font like the rest of the equation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! `\text` is meant for producing text mode material, not math mode text. Are you looking for `\mathrm`?

Comment: Thanks! That sets it to the correct font by itself! I'll just use `\mathrm` from now on.

Comment: @JosephWright -- this one might help someone else, so (unless it's a dup), an answer, please.

Comment: @JosephWright And may be expanding about the dos and don'ts of `\mathrm`, `\mathit`, `\mathup`, `\text`, `\textup`, `\textrm`, `\textit` in math mode. I have myself doubts about their use.

Comment: @Manuel see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130510/write-text-correctly-in-equations/130525#130525