# Why does LaTeX drop the first letter of my variable name in an equation?

Tags: math-mode

Friends: Can anybody tell me why the letter "e" of entropy does not show up in the following snippet?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal entropy[9,5] & = \mathcal - [(\frac{9}{14})*lg(\frac{9}{14}) + (\frac{5}{14})*lg(\frac{5}{14})] \\
& = - [(\frac{9}{14})*((lg(9)-lg(14)) + (\frac{5}{14})*((lg(5) - lg(14))] \\
& = - [(\frac{9}{14})*(\frac{log(9)}{log(2)}) - (\frac{log(14)}{log(2)}) + (\frac{5}{14})*(\frac{log(5)}{log(2)}-\frac{log(14}{log(2)})]\\
& = 0.940
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you want your `\mathcal` to do?

Comment: I am trying to write entropy = numerical expression

Comment: and continue in the next line working with the numerical expression but only after the equal sign. I do not want to keep repteating entropty =. Thanks for your time

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. What is your `\mathcal` supposed to do for you?

Comment: Also related more generally: [How bad for TeX is omitting braces {}, even if the result is the same?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/82329)

Comment: also use `\log` not `log` and similarly for other operators

Comment: If you want to spell out words like `log` and `entropy` in upright letters, that’s `\operatorname{}` or if you want to insert snippets of text, that’s the `\text{}` command from `amsmath`. I’m guessing that’s what you meant instead of `\mathcal`, but I’m not sure.

Answer (score 11):

The following example

- removes `\mathcal` that does not seem to have a purpose,
- fixes parentheses,
- sets `entropy` as text word and not as product of variables *e*, *n*, *t*, ...,
- sets the operators `lg` and `log` in upright font,
- tries to improve the formatting by

  - better sizes of the brackets,
  - removal of unneeded brackets,
  - removal of unneeded operators (*),
  - using package `siunitx` for formatting the final number.

The example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{siunitx}
% For text in math, see comments.
\newcommand*{\tx}{\textnormal}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\tx{entropy}[9,5]
& = - \mleft[\frac{9}{14}\lg\Bigl(\frac{9}{14}\Bigr)
  + \frac{5}{14}\lg\Bigl(\frac{5}{14}\Bigr)\mright] \\
& = -
  \mleft[
    \frac{9}{14}\bigl(\lg(9)-\lg(14)\bigr)
    +
    \frac{5}{14}\bigl(\lg(5) - \lg(14)\bigr)
  \mright] \\
& = -
  \mleft[
    \frac{9}{14} \left(\frac{\log(9)}{\log(2)} - \frac{\log(14)}{\log(2)}\right)
    +
    \frac{5}{14} \left(\frac{\log(5)}{\log(2)}-\frac{\log(14)}{\log(2)}\right)
  \mright]\\
& \approx \num{0.9402859586}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The formula between the `\left` and `\right` brackets are put in a "inner" math formula. This can cause additional horizontal space around the formula, for example, there is a thin space between an unary minus symbol and the opening bracket. `\mleft` and `\mright` of package `mleftright` avoids this.

Comment: If you change all instances of `\left[` and `\right]` to `\biggl[` and `\biggr]`, respectively, TeX will have a chance to treat the initiai `-` symbols as a unary rather than as a binary operators, by reducing the amount of whitespace between `-` and `\biggl[`.

Comment: @Mico The minus sign after a relation symbol can never be a binary math atom. The space (`\thinmuskip`) is added between the unary minus sign as ordinary math atom and the inner math formula by `\left` and `\right`. I have updated the answer to use `\mleft`  and `\mright` of package `mleftright` instead.

Comment: Probably `\mathrm{entropy}` is better.

Comment: @egreg Unhappily, there is no "best" way, just different ways with more or less advantages and disadvantages depending on the current situation. More details, e.g.: [Write 'text' **correctly** in equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130510/16967)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Sorry, but `\text` is wrong anyway. If the equation is part of a theorem statement, “entropy” would be typeset in italics.

Comment: @egreg `\mathrm` is also wrong, it fails for text with text accents, for example. For my taste, using italics in theorems is horrible. Depending on the font settings, `\textnormal` is often a good compromise, but the name is lengthy. The best is probably a user macro that can be defined depending on the use cases, formatting requirements, and taste.

Answer (score 10):

`\mathcal` is a macro with an argument. In your example, because of lack of `{...}`, the argument is `e`. But `\mathcal` works only with capital letters, hence the side effect.

Additionally, `\mathcal` is typically used to denote families of sets. It seems that you wanted some other effect.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to say entropy = math expression and continue on the next line but only working at the right hand side of the equal sign. There are about 5 lines of simple math manipulation. I am newbie in LATEX. What do you mean by (...)?

Comment: @RamonA.Mata-Toledo `{...}` was for an argument, e.g. `\matcal{Z}`.

Comment: In `unicode-math`, `\mathcal` is defined for small Latin letters.  U+212E is the Unicode character for script small letter *e*. The legacy `stix` package defines a `\mathscr{e}`. Agreed that it’s being used in error here, however.

Comment: "`\mathcal` is typically used to...". Well, no, people use it for many other types of objects. I agree that in this case it is a slightly weird choice, though.