# How to print "~" in order to put text above it

Tags: stacking-symbols

[How do I put text over symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74125/how-do-i-put-text-over-symbols) gives some very good answers to placing text above a symbol (=), which works for many other symbols which as +, @ etc. However none of the solutions work for `~`, I had to resort to `\sim` (see picture) to get the desired result.

Why do these not work?

`\newcommand\myeq{\stackrel{\mathclap{\normalfont\mbox{s}}}{~}}`

`$\Lambda \stackrel{s}{~} A$`

(Again, replacing `~` with `\sim` worked.)

MWE

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
 %\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \newcommand\myeq{\stackrel{\mathclap{\normalfont\mbox{s}}}{~}}
 % \newcommand\myeq{\stackrel{\mathclap{\normalfont\mbox{s}}}{\sim}}

 \begin{document}
    $\Lambda \stackrel{s}{~} A$

    $\Lambda \stackrel{s}{\sim} A$

    $\Lambda \myeq A$    
 \end{document}
```

[image: S relation]

Comment: `~` is a special character in TeX System, an active character which usually represents non-breakable space. I does not print the symbol "~". The corect tilde symbol is printed with `\sim`.

Comment: @Moriambar Ah! thx. If you put that line as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Done as you wished

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`~` is a special character in TeX System, an active character which usually represents non-breakable space. I does not print the symbol "~". The corect tilde symbol is printed with `\sim`.