# Suppress a line drawn by forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, linguistics, line

With the following code based on @cfr's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389570/9077) to [Specify length of each line in forest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389535/specify-length-of-each-line-in-forest), I get the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest, amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree = {%
            parent anchor = south,
            child anchor = north,
            s sep = 0em,
            tier/.option = level}
        [, phantom
            [a]
            [r]
            [c]
            [h]
            [i]
            [p]
            [$\stackrel{*}{\text{e}}$
                [$\stackrel{*}{\text{H}}$]]
            [l]
            [a
                [L]]
            [g]
            [o]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My question is simple: how can I suppress the line drawn between `a` and `L`? I want the `L` to be exactly where it is - I just don't want a line to the `a`. I've browsed through the documentation for [`forest`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) for how to prevent a line from being drawn, but I can't find anything.

In case anyone wants to know: I'm going to present this in two steps. In step 1 the `L` on the bottom level is not associated with anything on the top level ( = no line). In step 2 a rule kicks in which associates the `L` with the `a` (= line drawn). The code above shows step 2. I want to know how I can get step 1.

Comment: Are you using Beamer? If so, you can specify the tree just once with a suitable overlay specification. If it is really for `article` or whatever, obviously, this doesn't apply.

Comment: `s sep'=0mm` is quicker (with the quote mark - spacing doesn't matter). `parent anchor=children, child anchor=parent` is more flexible (though whether this is an advantage or not depends - I doubt it would bring much benefit here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `no edge` to the `[L]` node: (see p. 45 of the docs).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest, amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree = {%
            parent anchor = south,
            child anchor = north,
            s sep = 0em,
            tier/.option = level}
        [, phantom
            [a]
            [r]
            [c]
            [h]
            [i]
            [p]
            [$\stackrel{*}{\text{e}}$
                [$\stackrel{*}{\text{H}}$]]
            [l]
            [a
                [L,no edge]]
            [g]
            [o]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]