# How to stack a symbol on another of same size but with no vertical centering?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, stacking-symbols

I have something like

```
\[a = \langle a + b, c + d, e + f \rangle\]
```

But I want to stack another vector right above the right hand side, centered horizontally (with respect to corresponding elements of a), but without angle brackets, namely

```
        x      y      z
a = < a + b, c + d, e + f >
```

I tried `\overset` but it's not satisfactory because the upper vector will be smaller. I also tried `\genfrac` but it pushes the original vector down. (I don't want the angle brackets to extend to cover two lines.) How can I achieve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How do I put text over symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74125/5764)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions. The first uses a modified form of the `\overset` macro, in which the first argument is set in `\textstyle` rather than the default `\scriptstyle`. The second uses an `array` environment; it requires a bit more setup, but it's more flexible/versatile than the first. E.g., it's more straightforward changing the vertical spacing when using the second method.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\myoverset[2]{\overset{\textstyle #1\mathstrut}{#2}}
\newcommand\mycomma{,\mkern3mu} % emulate punctuation spacing
\begin{document}

\[
a = \langle \myoverset{x}{a + b}, 
            \myoverset{y}{c + d}, 
            \myoverset{z}{e + f} \rangle
\]

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
&x && y && z &\\
a=\langle &a+b &\mycomma& c+d &\mycomma& e+f &\rangle
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems I can use `displaystyle` in `\overset` as well!

Comment: sadly, the baselines of the letters in the uppermost line aren't aligned vertically.  that could be adjusted by adding a `\mathstrut` to each.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Great suggestion! I'll modify the first answer accordingly.

Comment: @YiFei - Using `\displaystyle` instead of `\textstyle` in the first argument of `\myoverset` will make a difference if the overset material contains superscripts and/or subscripts or if it contains "large" symbols such as `\sum` and `\int`. For the symbols `x`, `y`, and `z`, though, no change will occur.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a bottom aligned array:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\adorn}[2]{\begin{array}[b]{@{}c@{}}#2\\#1\end{array}}

\begin{document}

\[
A=\langle \adorn{a+b}{x},\adorn{c+d}{y},\adorn{e+f}{z} \rangle
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Overset}[2]{%
  \mathop{#2}\limits^{\vbox to -.1ex{%
  \kern -1.4ex\hbox{$#1$}\vss}}}

\begin{document}

\[ a = \langle \Overset{x}{a + b},\Overset{y}{c + d},\Overset{z}{e + f} \rangle \]

\[ a = \langle a + b, c + d, e + f \rangle \]

\begin{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, I have defined a new command called `\Overset`.

Comment: @Mico Please feel free to change my code to one of those solutions you propose. Be my guest!

Answer (score 4):

Here, `stackengine` is suited.  One can change the stack baselineskip, as shown, with the `\setstackgap` invocation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\mathstack[2]{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{\Lstackgap}{{}#1{}}{#2}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}
\begin{document}
\[a = \langle a \mathstack{+}{x} b, c \mathstack{+}{y} d, e \mathstack{+}{z} f \rangle\]
\setstackgap{L}{1.3\baselineskip}
\[a = \langle a \mathstack{+}{x} b, c \mathstack{+}{y} d, e \mathstack{+}{z} f \rangle\]
\end{document}
```

[image]