# How to put a text over symbols, part 2

Tags: lengths, syntax

Building on [How do I put text over symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74125/how-do-i-put-text-over-symbols) I created a new command :

```
\newcommand{\myequ}[1]{\stackrel{\mathclap{\normalfont\mbox{#1}}}{=}}
```

which gives overwriting :

[image]

when `#1` is too long. Is there a way to tweak the new command so that it could take the length of `#1` into account automatically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `\mathclap`, whose very purpose is to hide the width of its argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\myequ}[1]{\stackrel{\normalfont\mbox{#1}}{=}}
\begin{document}
\[
y \myequ{eq.(3.3.44)} \int_\Omega x\,dx
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also wish to consider using `\small` or `\scriptsize` in preference to `\normalfont`.

Thanks to Bernard for reminding me of `\eqmakebox`, which can help for cases where `align` is involved:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,eqparbox}
\newcommand{\myequ}[1]{\stackrel{\scriptsize\mbox{#1}}{=}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
y \eqmakebox[][c]{$\myequ{eq.(3.3.44)}$}& \int_\Omega x\,dx\\
z_1 \eqmakebox[][c]{$\myequ{eq.(576)}$}& \int_\Omega x^{(2+ 3x)}\,dx
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good point about char sizing, I did it in the meantime

Comment: One last bit though : this does mix super well with alignment. Is there a priviledge solution for that ? ("=" symbols won't aligned if two distrinct `#1`'s have different lenghts

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj You are correct that `align` structures will be affected.

Comment: You can nest the `=` in  an `\eqmakebox`  (from `eqparbox`) to maintain the alignment.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you.  I seemed to recall that such a thing existed, but had never used it nor could I recall its name.

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj Thanks to suggestion of Bernard, the `align` case can be addressed.