# Is it possible to stack symbols on top of another and how do I make letters vary in size?

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

What I want to do is to place a letter on top of another. Specifically because I want to be able to write a specific representation of Greek numerals with large numbers.

I just need to be able to put any Greek letter above a Mu or just M in the Greek alphabet.

I also want to write some symbols smaller than others. How do I do that?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74125

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner The  tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74125 is LaTeX specific, but this question is not LaTeX specific. So, it is not duplicate.

Comment: @wipet Ok, thanks for the clarification. I do not see this difference, but I am sure that you know what you are talking about :). Should I vote for reopening?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this??

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\setstackgap{L}{.8\baselineskip}
\newcommand\greekstack[2]{\stackon{#1}{\scriptscriptstyle#2}}
\begin{document}
\greekstack{\alpha}{1}
\greekstack{\lambda}{30}
\greekstack{\rho}{100}

\bigskip
\greekstack{\mu}{\gamma}
\greekstack{M}{\delta}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\def\greekstack#1#2{\leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip\halign{\hss$##$\hss\cr\scriptstyle#2\cr\mathstrut#1\cr}}}

\greekstack{\alpha}{1}
\greekstack{\lambda}{30}
\greekstack{\rho}{100}
\medskip
\greekstack{\mu}{\gamma}
\greekstack{M}{\delta}

\bye
```