# What is a simple way to create a binary relation symbol on top of another?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, relation-symbols

What is a simple way to have `\ll` on top of `\gg` with equal size and vertically center aligned and have them work as a binary relation symbol like `\lessgtr`? The commands `\underset` and `\overset` cannot be used because they do not treat the two symbols equally, and they do not vertically center.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try `substack`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ggll}{\mathrel{\substack{\ll\\[-.05em]\gg}}}

$x\ggll x$

$x\substack{\ll\\\gg}x$

\end{document}
```

I added `amsmath` for `\lessgtr` but it also needed for `substack`. You may read more about this command in the `amsmath` documentation or in the `mathmode` paper.
As @tohecz pointed out, one may need some spacing correction by `mathrel`. Furthermore i added a vertical correction with the optional argument of `\\`. This makes the symbol a little bit more like belonging together (and might be a thing of personal taste too).

[image: l#1: with corrections; l#2: without]

Comment: You might want to add `\mathrel{\substack{...}}` for the proper spacing.

Comment: @tohecz indeed i want;)

Comment: Just wanted to add that I used this solution to create a nice inline i.i.d. distributed symbol. I haven't found a question about it, so I thought I'd add it for future seekers..

Answer (score 10):

I doubt that you really want such an ugly symbol, but here are two proposals:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\llgg}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\llggi\relax}}
\newcommand{\llggi}[2]{\vcenter{\offinterlineskip\hbox{$#1\ll$}\hbox{$#1\gg$}}}

\newcommand{\sllgg}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\sllggi\relax}}
\newcommand{\sllggi}[2]{\vcenter{\offinterlineskip\hbox{$\mkern2mu#1\ll$}\hbox{$#1\gg\mkern2mu$}}}

\begin{document}
$a\llgg b \lessgtr c_{\llgg}$

$a\sllgg b \lessgtr c_{\sllgg}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

One might add some vertical space in the first version, but I'd prefer the second one, in which I add instead a little horizontal shift.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer has helped me to concoct a `\preceqq` sign without loading extra fonts packages! I ended up doing

`\newcommand{\preceqq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\preceqqi\relax}}`
 
`\newcommand{\preceqqi}[2]{\vcenter{\offinterlineskip\lineskip1pt\hbox{$#1\prec$}\hbox{$#1=$}}}`

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest putting two `\lessgtr` in a roll, with a good space inbetween so that the lines join each other nicely:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\newcommand\llgg{\lessgtr\mkern-5.7mu\lessgtr}

\begin{document}
$a\llgg b$

$f_{a\llgg b}$

$g_{h_{a\llgg b}}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use `stackrel` or `stackbin` commands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb,stackrel}

\begin{document}

$$ A\stackbin[\text{and}]{}{+} B \stackrel[x]{!}{=} C$$

$$ A\stackbin{\ll}{\gg} B $$

\end{document}
```

You can find useful the [following post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39225/differences-between-stackrel-and-stackbin)

Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried to compile the code? It doesn't really look like one complicated relational symbol. The upper part is smaller.