# LyX: How to combine two math symbols?

Tags: symbols, lyx

I'm a new user of LyX. I'm using it to write math lectures.

How can I make a new symbol from two existing ones? To be more precise, how can I create this:

[image]

It's a subset with a circle in it (`\subset`, `\circ`).

Comment: If this question can be reopened, then [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156013/16967) can be moved here, where it fits better than as answer for the duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how friendly my answer is to a new LyX user... but

`\!` can be used to give negative horizontal spacing in math mode.
Wrapping with `\mathrel{}` adjust the spacing around the new symbol.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\subsetcirc}{\mathrel{\subset\!\!\!\!\!\circ}}
\begin{document}
$A \subset B$

$A \subsetcirc B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

See also: [question on how to create symbol on top of each other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89265/43005)

Comment: More related: [\subseteq + \circ as a single symbol (“open subset”)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/subseteq-circ-as-a-single-symbol-open-subset).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses the TeX "primitive" commands `\ooalign`, `\kern`, and `\raise` (as well as `\hss`, `\cr`, and `\hbox`). It also uses, unsurprisingly, the "standard" symbols `\subset` and `\circ`.

[image]

If you want to make the circle larger or smaller, change the first argument of the `\scalebox` command. To shift the circle a bit more to the right, increase the argument of the `\kern` command. And, if you use a package that uses its own forms of the subset and circle symbols, you may need to tweak the code a bit more to get a satisfactory positioning of the symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \scalebox macro
\newcommand\subsetcirc{%
  \mathrel{\ooalign{\hss$\subset$\hss\cr%
  \kern0.6ex\raise0.2ex\hbox{\scalebox{0.7}{$\circ$}}}}}

\begin{document}
$A\subsetcirc B$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\subsetcircle{\mathrel{\ooalign{$\subset$\cr\hidewidth\hbox{$\circ\mkern 1mu$}\cr}}}

\begin{document}

$A\subsetcircle B$

\end{document}
```

[image: output]