# Why 'displaystyle' is not working?

Tags: displaystyle

I am typing some mathematical expression related to 'displaystyle'. This is working well for `$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=1$`. But it is not working in the following example :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$P \displaystyle\simeq_p Q$
\end{document}
```

This gives :
[image]

But my desired output is :
[image]

Anyone can tell me what is the problem here ?

Comment: The result is what I expect from `\simeq_p`. Why do you think it should be different? Setting displaystyle doesn't stack symbols as far as I know.

Comment: You should usually use `\stackrel` from the [stackrel package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/stackrel) or `\underset` from the amsmath package for such constructions.  Cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39225/15925

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8):

Only limits on `\mathop` operators (like `\sum`) change in dispaystyle. Limits on relational infix operators stay in subscript position.

You could do

```
$P \displaystyle\mathrel{\mathop{\simeq}_p} Q$
```

To locally get mathop positioning and then make the construct a relation again.

Comment: @SoumitraSen thanks (you don't have to accept, but if you want to accept you need to click on the accept button to make the tick mark)