# Write above the symbol math "subset"

Tags: math-mode, stacking-symbols

Like the symbols "bigcup or bigcap" in LateX, I'd like to write above the symbol subset.

I have try to use the displaystyle command, but it doesn't work !

Here is a snippet of my try :

`$\boldsymbol{NP} \displaystyle\subset^{?} \boldsymbol{P}$`

Comment: You could also use `\shortstack{?\\$\subset$}`

Answer (score 9):

Usually `\overset` is used for that purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$A\overset{?}{\subset}B$

$A\subset B$
\end{document}
```

The second formula is just for showing that the spacing for a relation symbol is preserved.

[image]

Comment: I use \stackrel for this. Is overset better?

Comment: @ChrisChudzicki: Sorry for the necromancy, but see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39230/40862 (so according to that answer yes, overset is better, because it takes care of spacing properly, without you having to figure out if something is a relation or a binary operator; if you *do* know that, the result will probably be the same).