# Notes between lines

Tags: typography, reledmac

There's any way on LaTeX to make a note between lines of the normal text? Exactly like this:
[image: Note]

In this case, the note/var ("r") over the "t" character...

Comment: `\underset` and `\overset` commands are your friends: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39230/31034

Comment: This is so simple... Thank you very much... If you want to make the response I'm happy to confirm it to put the question as answered...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\overset` with `amsmath` package in math mode is a possible solution.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\os}[2]{${\overset{\text{#1}}{\text{#2}}}$}
\begin{document}
Vat. has \textit{an\os{r}{t}e:}

Vat. has an\os{r}{t}e:
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This obviously works -- but strictly speaking math-typesetting should be reserved for typesetting mathematics ... Especially if you use this kind of arrangement more often or if you need a specific font, you should look into the [`stackengine`-package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stackengine)