# Error with \overset in caption and \figurelistpage

Tags: captions

I have the following tex document:

```
\documentclass[phd,tocprelim]{cornell}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,pstricks}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{hangcaption}
\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{\singlespacing\hangcaption{#1}\normalspacing}

\newcommand{\squig}[2]{\overset{ #1 }{\rightsquigarrow}_{ #2 }}

\begin{document}

\figurelistpage

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{test.png}
\caption{$\squig{1}{2}$}
\label{my fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And I get the following errors, which disappear when I comment out `\figurelistpage` OR if I change the caption to something not involving `\overset`:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
\inaccessible
l.1 ...\rightarrow }\limits ^{n\to \infty }}$}}{2}
%
Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text>
\endgroup
l.1 ...\rightarrow }\limits ^{n\to \infty }}$}}{2}
%
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
)
```

I don't need the figure list page, however in my full document I still get the following error on the line containing the caption with `\overset` after commenting out `\figurelistpage`:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@tempa ->\catcode `\<
12\relax \catcode `\>12\relax \catcode `\=12\relax
l.2975 ... $\rightsquigarrow_2$. $\overset{1}{=}$}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I have not been able to reproduce this error in the pared-down example. Any clue what is going on? Is there a different way I could define my `\squig` command to get around this?

Edit: Replacing `\overset` with `\stackrel` gets rid of the error, but I'm told I [shouldn't use stackrel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39225/differences-between-stackrel-and-stackbin).

Comment: Try using `\protect\overset` instead of just `\overset` in your definition of `\squig`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixes it!

Answer (score 1):

Either use `\protect\squig` when in captions, or use `\DeclareRobustCommand` at the outset, if you plan to frequently use the symbol in captions:

```
\newcommand{\squig}{}% just to make sure it is not defined
\DeclareRobustCommand{\squig}[2]{\overset{ #1 }{\rightsquigarrow}_{ #2 }}
```

The dummy `\newcommand{\squig}{}` is used to ensure the command is not already defined (maybe by a package you load), because `\DeclareRobustCommand` silently overwrites existing commands.

Load neither `graphics` (it is already loaded by `graphicx`) nor `epsfig`, which only exists for compatibility with documents written pre-1995.

Also `subfigure` is obsolete; use either `subfig` or `subcaption`.