# How to place the subscript below and above the box

Tags: formatting, boxes

I wanted to put the subscript below and above the box (shown in image), similar to how it happens for `\sum`. `\displaystyle` is not applicable. How can I make it placed there?

[image]

Here is my definition of the box:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,setspace}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\mcirc{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\bigcirc}{t}}}
\def\msquare{\mathord{\scalebox{1}[1]{\scalerel*{\Box}{\strut}}}}

\begin{document}
$\msquare_{i=1}^{k} C_{n_i}$
\end{document|
```

Comment: What about `\underset`, `\overset` and/or `\overunderset` as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39230/244141)?

Comment: Welcome. // Please make it a habit in this place to embed your example in complete enough code, which we can copy and run. Latex is complex and powerful, and oftentimes the first few code lines are important.

Comment: Replace `\mathord` with `\mathop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace `\mathord` with `\mathop`. Of course, the limits will be above and below only in display style.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,setspace}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand\mcirc{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\bigcirc}{t}}}
\newcommand\msquare{\mathop{\scalerel*{\Box}{\strut}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\msquare_{i=1}^{k} C_{n_i} \mcirc X
\]
\begin{center}
$\msquare_{i=1}^{k} C_{n_i} \mcirc X$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I'm not sure you want the same size in display and text style. Anyway, I removed the useless `\scalebox`.

Comment: Thank you so much! big help!