# Conditional whitespace in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing

## Clarification

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\def\foo{What do I put here???}
\begin{document}
\[a \foo b\]         
\[\foo b\]
\[a, \foo b\]
\[a, b\]
\end{document}
```

I would like the document just above to be equivalent to the following one. What should I put as a definition for the \foo command?

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[a\quad{}\forall{}b\]         
\[\forall{}b\]
\[a,\forall{}b\]
\[a,\;\forall{}b\]
\end{document}
```

## Original question

How can I reproduce the spacing behaviour of, the `+` operator in math mode, but with different spacing.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\begin{document}
\[a + b\]         
\[+ b\]
\[a, + b\]
\[a, b\]
\end{document}
```

In the document above, + has a space on either side in `a + b`, but has no space before or after in `+ b`. How can I write a command with a spacing behaviour similar to `+`, that is having different spacing size depending on what's before (and what's after, too, if possible)?

I thought about using flexible glue, but I think it's a feature to have a space which can vary depending on how full the line is, instead of a space which varies depending on the surrounding tokens.

Note: I'm not looking for `\operatorname{}`. Instead, I'm trying to re-implement it, but with different spacing.

Comment: Your objective isn't entirely clear, I'm afraid. For instance, after mentioning several possible spacing outcomes, you write "How can I write a command with similar spacing behaviour"? *Similar to what?* TeX has detailed rules to determine the whitespace settings between objects ("atoms") of type mathord, mathrel, mathbin, mathpunct, mathopen, mathclose, etc. Which of these rules are you looking to mimic in the command you're looking to create? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico I'm trying to mimic their general behaviour, not a specific one. I want to be able to have space or not around a piece of text or character, depending on what's surrounding it. I edited my post for clarification. Please tell me if it's still not clear.

Comment: the `+` is defined as a binary operator, so you might try defining your new "operator" as `\mathbin{xx}` and letting the built-in rules take over.

Comment: @barbarabeeton How would I change the spacing of `\mathbin`, then? Like, have it output a `\quad` either side, instead of just a normal math space?

Comment: `+` is a `\mathbin`. It's behavior is hard-coded in the TeX engine. If you want the same behavior for a different symbol, then put it in `\mathbin{...}`.

Comment: Automatic spacing depending on context can only be obtained by sticking to the predefined atom types. There's a big limitation in the fact that *only* one value for each of `\thinmuskip`, `\medmuskip` and `\thickmuskip` is used in a formula. So, if you define something to produce a `\mathrel` atom, it will be surrounded by `\thickmuskip` determined from the value current at the end of the formula.

Comment: The space is `\medmuskip` (used in `\>`).

Comment: In your first example -- `a+b` -- the `+` symbol (an object of type `mathbin`) is located between two objects of type `mathord`; in consequence, `+` is treated as a binary operator and whitespace in the amount of `\medmuskip` is inserted on either side. In the second example, `+` is not preceded by any (math) object and is thus treated as a `unary` operator, i.e., no whitespace is inserted between `+` and `b`. You'll have to pick up a copy of the TeXbook to get a hold of all possible combinations and of the associated spacing rules.

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron You find the table for spacings between atoms at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81777/4427

Comment: @egreg, @Mico I added an example of what I want my command to do. If I understand correctly what you say, what I want isn't possible because the spacing behaviour of `\mathbin` and co. is hardcoded into TeX, and one can't create similar behaviour with different spacing and conditions. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron Yes, you did.

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron I'll do it later, if nobody comes along.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You find a table of the spacings automatically inserted by TeX in math mode at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81777/4427. The particular spacings for `+` derive from the fact that it is classified as a **Bin** atom and from the rules that disallow a **Bin** atom, transforming it into **Ord**, if it is not surrounded by possible combinations. So, for instance, **Close** **Bin** **Ord** is allowed and in `$(a-b)+2$` the `+` has `\medmuskip` on either side.

The parameters that hold the value of the automatic spacings are `\thinmuskip` (“1” in the table), `\medmuskip` (“2” in the table) and `\thickmuskip` (“3” in the table).

An important fact is that *only one* value for each of the above parameters is used throughout a formula, precisely the value that's current when the `$` that closes the formula is scanned and TeX starts the process of transforming the math list it has built into a horizontal list, according to the rules explained in Appendix G of the TeXbook.

So, if you try doing `$a\begingroup\thickmuskip=18mu+\endgroup b$` you still get

[image]

No matter how you reset the values of the parameters, a **Bin** atom will always have *the same* space on either side of it.

It's a limitation built in TeX that the user has no way to influence the automatic selection of spacings, nor we can do tests about the previous or the following atom. With some clever macros one can identify whether a following atom is **Ord**, **Bin** or **Rel** (see the `\binrel@` macro in `amsbsy.sty`, which is used for `\overset` and `\underset` of `amsmath`), but there's no possibility of testing the previous atom.

Things may be different with LuaTeX and its callbacks that can examine the lists being built and research on this would be very welcome, because it could give ways for extending the inflexible paradigma of TeX. There are other cases in which some flexibility would be needed; even better, defining new types of atoms and new spacing parameters could solve some problems that now require *ad hoc* input.

However, my impression is that you're looking at the problem of `\forall` from the wrong point of view. My position about the symbol is that it should never be used except in formal logic. People can obviously disagree, but in this case they should place `\forall` *before*, not after the term it quantifies. Otherwise, use “for all”, which is clearer and is less ambiguous with respect to placement.