# Improper alignment at equation break

Tags: equations, align

I have the following MWE, showing how the two plus-signs of the second equation are not completely aligned with each other:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
f_\beta &= f_\beta \\
f_\beta &= + (-\Omega_{f_\beta})|_{(r, q)} \\
        &\phantom{{}=} + (-\Omega_{f_\beta})|_{(r, q)} \notag \\
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I am using `\phantom{{}=}`, what else is needed to make the alignment correct for the `+`-signs, while keeping the alignment of the `=`-signs as well?

Comment: use ` = {} & ` in the first row, and just `&` in the second. Basically you are align on the right of a relation, in which case care is needed to get `=` to use the correct spacing

Comment: @daleif Thanks for the swift reply. I updated my question to account for a more general case, where the current `phantom`-approach is better. Using your method wont align the `=`-signs

Comment: If you want to align on the `+` symbols, use `&+` instead of `&=`.

Comment: I'd still go with @daleif's approach: use `={}&` in the first two lines, and just `&` in the third one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the third line you have, after the alignment point,

```
{} \phantom{{}=} + (
```

(the first is automatically inserted) that makes four atoms

> **Ord** **Ord** **Bin** **Open**

so this inserts spaces as

> **Ord** (zero) **Ord** (`\medmuskip`) **Bin** (`\medmuskip`) **Open**

In the second line you have, instead

```
{} = + (
```

that produces the list of atoms

> **Ord** **Rel** ***Bin*** **Open**

but the third atom doesn't make sense as a **Bin**, so it becomes **Ord** and the spacing is

> **Ord** (`\thickmuskip`) **Rel** (`\thickmuskip`) **Ord** (zero) **Open**

Note that in the phantom you have “**Ord** (`\thickmuskip`) **Rel**” so this should explain the misalignments. In particular, the space between `+` and `(` in the third line, that's not present in the second line.

Solution: a better phantom, with `{}` on either side, but embedded in a `\mathopen`, so the `+` will turn into an **Ord** like in the second line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\fakeeq}{\mathopen{\hphantom{{}={}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
f_\beta &= f_\beta \\
f_\beta &= + (-\Omega_{f_\beta})|_{(r, q)} \\
        &\fakeeq + (-\Omega_{f_\beta})|_{(r, q)} \notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, don't make TeX into considering `+` as a unary symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
f_\beta ={}& f_\beta \\
f_\beta ={}& + (-\Omega_{f_\beta})|_{(r, q)} \\
           & + (-\Omega_{f_\beta})|_{(r, q)} \notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this case you may want to remove the `\medmuskip` on the left side of `+`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
f_\beta ={}& f_\beta \\
f_\beta ={}& \mspace{-\medmuskip} + (-\Omega_{f_\beta})|_{(r, q)} \\
           & \mspace{-\medmuskip} + (-\Omega_{f_\beta})|_{(r, q)} \notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For a review of the spacing rules, see [What's the right space to right the alignment of a right aligned align environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81752/)

Comment: I know the spacing rules from the TeXBook and I regularly forget them: do you happen to know whether they are explained or summarized somewhere here on the site? If a question/answer deals with them it would be nice to link answers like yours.

Comment: @campa This answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81777/4427 perhaps?

Comment: Precisely! Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You could nest an `aligned` environment inside the `align` environment. In the "outer" `align` environment, perform alignment on the `=` symbols. In the "inner" `aligned` environment, perform alignment on the `+` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
f_\beta &= f_\beta \\
f_\beta &= \!\begin{aligned}[t]
             &+ (-\Omega_{f_\beta})|_{(r, q)} \\
             &+ (-\Omega_{f_\beta})|_{(r, q)}
           \end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If the `+` symbols should be treated as unary rather than as binary operators, it suffices to encase them in curly braces (which converts their status to `mathord`). TeX has different spacing rules for `-` and `+` depending on whether they are unary or binary operators.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
f_\beta &= f_\beta \\
f_\beta &= \!\begin{aligned}[t]
             &{+} (-\Omega_{f_\beta})|_{(r, q)} \\
             &{+} (-\Omega_{f_\beta})|_{(r, q)}
           \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```