# Horizontal spacing with \circ and \cos

Tags: spacing, math-operators

I need to write

```
$\sin\circ \theta \cos\circ \theta$
```

with correct horizontal spacing (here \theta denotes a real-valued function). How can I do that? Can you please explain me briefly why my code does not work fine?

Here is what I get

[image]

Comment: `\circ` is a binary relation, which of course has consequences on spacing (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81777/82917)). But I'm not sure about what spacing you are expecting.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Just code `\sin{\circ]\theta\cos{\circ}\theta` so that `\circ` be considered as an`ordinary` math atom. However shouldn't it  be typeset as`^{\circ}`, or better, as `\sin\textdegree\theta`?

Comment: @Bernard There is no difference between `\sin\circ` and `\sin{\circ}`, since a `Bin` atom (`\circ`) is anyway converted to `Ord` if preceded by an `Op` atom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make `\sin` into an ordinary, for this case, so `\circ` will be surrounded by items compatible with its nature of binary operation.

Your code has the sequence **Op** **Bin** **Ord** and, by rule, the **Bin** (that is, `\circ`) becomes **Ord**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\fsin}{\mathord{\sin}}
\newcommand{\fcos}{\mathord{\cos}}

\begin{document}

\[
\fsin\circ \theta \qquad \fcos\circ \theta
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need to have them as terms of a multiplication, but with your solution removing \qquad still gives a problem

Comment: @MK7 It's no different from `a\circ b c\circ d`; I believe that `(\fsin\circ\theta)(\fcos\circ\theta)` would make your intentions clearer. Otherwise, add `\,` in between: `\fsin\circ\theta\,\fcos\circ\theta`.

Comment: This is just equivalent to `{\sin}\circ`