# Gaps in math-mode

Tags: math-mode

I would like to know, why there is a gap between `Rep` and `Q` but not between `Rep` and `S`. How can I get a gap between `Rep` and `S` as long as for `Rep Q`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Q}{\mathsf{Q}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\RQ}{\mathbf{Rep}\Q}

\begin{document}
$\RQ\quad\mathbf{Rep}\mathsf{S}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: TeX inserts a thin space between `\mathbf{Rep}` (an ordinary atom) and `\Q` (a math operator).

Comment: \quad is a space.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer My question is about the two spaces between Rep and the argument, i.e. Q or S.

Comment: @egreg How can I the space also between Rep and S?

Comment: You need to declare `\mathsf{S}` a math operator as you did with `\mathsf{Q}`. Note that `\S` is already defined by another macro.

Comment: Yes, thats the reason why I havn't defined it like that. Is there another way? Like a command for this space?

Comment: You can insert a thin space (`\,`) manually.

Comment: Can't you just use some other macroname than `\S`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following, the notation `(<object>)_{[mathord]}` means that "`(<object>)`" (or "atom") is of type "`mathord`" ("math-ordinary"), etc.

- `\RQ` gets expanded to `(\mathbf{Rep})_{[mathop]}(\mathbf{Q})_{[mathord]`, i.e, the first object "**Rep**" is of type `mathop` ("math-operator") and the second object ("**Q**") is of type `mathord`.
- `\mathbf{Rep}\mathsf{S}` contains two objects of type `mathord` -- "**Rep**" and "**S**".
- TeX does not insert whitespace between adjacent atoms of type `mathord`.
- In contrast, TeX automatically inserts a thinspace (1/6 of an emspace) if a `mathop` atom is followed by a `\mathord` atom. Two easy examples of such a pairwise combination are `\sin x` and `\log y`.

TeX knows 8 different types of math objects. These types are  `mathord`, `mathop`, `mathbin`, `mathrel`, `mathopen`, `mathclose`, mathpunct, and `mathinnner`. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81777/5001) by @egreg for a detailed table of all pairwise spacing rules.