# How to make spacing before \left the same as before \bigl?

Tags: math-mode

Compare result of the following two examples:

```
$1\mathopen{\hbox{$\left(\vbox to8.5pt{}\right.\nulldelimiterspace=0pt \mathsurround=0pt$}}$
\end
```

```
$1\left(\vbox to8.5pt{}\right.$
\end
```

Why `\left(` in the first example produces less spacing than in the second? (although the construction in the first example includes the construction from the second example as a subset, so, intuitively, effect should not be smaller)

Comment: You could add, *as needed*, a `\!` before the `\left` construction, to remove the thin space.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/is-it-ever-bad-to-use-left-and-right/173740#173740

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construction `\left<delim><math material>\right<delim>` forms an Inner atom, which is surrounded by thin spaces, by rule, *if* part of another formula, according to the spacing rules described in the TeXbook.

Compare

```
!$\left(x\right)$!

!$\left(x\right)x$!

!$x\left(x\right)x$!

\bye
```

[image]

See the spacing table in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81777/4427, or the original table in the TeX book, page 170.

In the `\bigl` construction, the math formula with `\left` and `\right` has no atom before `\left` and after `\right`, so no thin space is added.

You can use `mleftright.sty`, even with plain TeX:

```
\input mleftright.sty

!$\left(x\right)$!

!$\left(x\right)x$!

!$x\left(x\right)x$!

!$x\mleft(x\mright)x$!

\bye
```

[image]

Consult the source code of `mleftright.sty` in order to understand the trick.

Comment: For those who want to know the trick without looking into `mleftright.sty`: `!$x\mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup\left(x\aftergroup\egroup\right)x$!`

Comment: If one does not want to use `mleftryght.sty`, the following may be used: `!$x\mathopen{}\left(x\right)\mathclose{}x$!`, and if right delim is sub/super-scripted, `\mathclose{` should be put before `\left` instead.