# To which atoms correspond \left and \right in \showlists?

Tags: math-mode, tex-core

This is the input:

```
$\left|-\infty\right|\showlists$
\end
```

This is the output:

```
\mathinner
.\left"26A30C
.\mathbin
..\fam2 ^^@
.\mathord
..\fam2 1
.\right"26A30C
```

It is not clear to what atoms correspond `\left"26A30C` and `\right"26A30C`.
It cannot be *Open* and *Close*, because according to the table on p.170 of TeXbook *Open* cannot be followed by *Bin* (the table entry is `*`).

Comment: See also answer to exercise 19.7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You wrote,

> [The status of `\left|`] cannot be `Open` ..., because according to the table on p.170 of TeXbook `Open` cannot be followed by `Bin` (the table entry is `*`)

This interpretation of the table on p. 170 of the TeXbook is *not* entirely correct. See, e.g., @egreg's [who else?!] follow-up comment to me below [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81777/5001) to the question [What's the right space to right the alignment of a right aligned align environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81752/5001).

The better way to interpret the meaning of `*` in the table on p. 170 of the TeXbook is this: If TeX encounters an "impossible combination" -- such as `open` followed by `bin` -- then the status of the `bin` atom is changed to `ord`.

Let's apply this to `\left|-\infty\right|`:

- `\left|` has status `mathopen`.
- `-` has status `mathbin` by default. However, because `open/bin` is an "impossible" combination, the status of `-` is changed to `ord`. Observe that the end result is exactly as it should be, since `-` is a unary operator, not a binary operator, in the formula at hand.
- `\infty` has status `ord`. No problem either, since no extra space is inserted between `-` and `\infty` -- as is appropriate for a unary operator.
- `\right|` has status `mathclose`; still no problem.

Answer (score 6):

If you modify your example into

```
\tracingonline=1 \showboxdepth=\maxdimen \showboxbreadth=\maxdimen

$\mathopen|-\infty\mathclose| \left|-\infty\right|\showlists$\showlists
\end
```

you get on the terminal

```
### math mode entered at line 3
\mathopen
.\fam2 j
\mathbin
.\fam2 ^^@
\mathord
.\fam2 1
\mathclose
.\fam2 j
\mathinner
.\left"26A30C
.\mathbin
..\fam2 ^^@
.\mathord
..\fam2 1
.\right"26A30C
```

which should answer your question: the “change” of the `\mathbin` atom happens later, when spaces are being inserted during the conversion of the math list to a horizontal list. Indeed, the second `\showlists` yields

```
### horizontal mode entered at line 3
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
\mathon
\tensy j
\tensy ^^@
\tensy 1
\tensy j
\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.66663
\hbox(7.5+2.5)x23.33339
.\hbox(7.5+2.5)x2.77779
..\tensy j
.\tensy ^^@
.\tensy 1
.\hbox(7.5+2.5)x2.77779
..\tensy j
\mathoff
```

Note that the ASCII code of `j` is `"6A`, so in all cases the same glyph is used to realize the vertical bar.