# space after a comma in a subscript?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I have a problem with a space after a comma in a subscript.
I created a command called `\segN`, for intervals with integers. I want a `\thinspace` between the first integer and the comma, so I typed `#1\,,#2` in my command. The second integer should be separated from the comma by the regular space after a comma. It works fine but not in a subscript.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{newtxmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\segN}{\@ifstar\segN@star\segN@nostar}
\newcommand*{\segN@star}[2]{\left\dlb#1\,,#2\right\drb}
\newcommand*{\segN@nostar}[3][]{#1\dlb#2\,,#3#1\drb}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  $\segN{1}{2}$,\qquad$\displaystyle\sum_{k\in\segN{1}{2}}x_k$
\end{document}
```

In the first `\segN{1}{2}`, it's ok: the 2 is separated from the comma.
But in the second (with the subscript), the 2 is sticked to the comma and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space between a punctuation symbol and an ordinary symbol is a "conditional" `\thinmuskip`: "conditional" in the sense that it's not used in script styles: that's why you see it in the first example but not in the second one. (See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81777/82917) for more details.)

Quick fix: make everything a `\mathord` and insert *both* spaces manually.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{newtxmath}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\segN}[2]{\dlb}{\drb}{{#1}\,{,}\,{#2}}

% also a possibility but more complicated
%\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\segN}[2]{\dlb}{\drb}{#1\,,\,\nonscript\!#2}

\begin{document}
  $\segN{1}{2}$,\qquad$\displaystyle\sum_{k\in\segN{1}{2}}x_k$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Miscellaneous comments:

- `mathtools` already provides a way to define a paired delimiter with a starred version.
- Loading `newtxmath` without `newtxtext` looks weird to me.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. @campa: I use newtxtext but I didn't put it in the MWE. I didn't know DeclarePairedDelimiterX. I only knew DeclarePairedDelimiter. Big change for me

Comment: Since it is in scriptstyle, shouldn’t the space before and after the comma be smaller than in textstyle and displaystyle?

Comment: @Didier I'm not sure I understand your question. The space is a `\thinmuskip`, which scales with the current style.

Comment: Ok, campa. I didn’t know it was scaling with the current style. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Is it what You need?
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{newtxmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\segN}{\@ifstar\segN@star\segN@nostar}
\newcommand*{\segN@star}[2]{\left\dlb#1\,,#2\right\drb}
\newcommand*{\segN@nostar}[3][]{#1\dlb#2, \,#3#1\drb}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  $\segN{1}{2}$,\qquad$\displaystyle\sum_{k\in\segN{1}{2}}x_k$
\end{document}
```