# Make vertical space of each line similar in align environment

Tags: align

If we have several lines in align environment, with very different complexity, e.g. some nonsense code below

```
\begin{align*}
    a&=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\|b+\frac{\mathcal{C}}{d}\|_{L_2}}{\|\mathcal{E}\|_{L_\infty}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}R(x,y)\right)^\frac{a+\frac{d}{e}}{f}\\
    &=b+c
\end{align*}
```

[image: Vertical space very different]

The vertical space taken up by two lines are vastly different. It may be a desired feature of LaTeX, but when I have a large block of equations in my paper, it becomes extremely ugly.

[image: Paper]

Question:

1. Is there any way that can make vertical space taken by each line in align environment similar?
2. How to make the big equation block in my paper look better?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This isn't automatic, but should give the result you're looking for.  The tallest element in each line is an integral sign, so inserting a `\vphantom{\int}` in each shorter line will force the lines apart.

Comment: In that longer equation I would be more concerned about the bad spacing to the right of the `\leq`.

Comment: @mickep Could you explain more? I also find the spacing disturbing, but I don't know how to improve. Maybe I should flush `\leq` to the left?

Comment: It is difficult to give advice without knowing what you are doing, but maybe [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81777/52406) helps?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE, hoep `\jot` will help you, and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts,mathtools}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\jot}{16pt}%vary how much you like
\begin{align*}
    a&=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\|b+\frac{\mathcal{C}}{d}\|_{L_2}}{\|\mathcal{E}\|_{L_\infty}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}R(x,y)\right)^\frac{a+\frac{d}{e}}{f}\\
    &=b+c
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Another Method (thanks to `dalief`)**

```
\begin{spreadlines}{10pt}%%change how much you like
\begin{algin}
...
\end{align}
\end{spreadlines}
```

also will works

Comment: `mathtools` has an env for doing that locally: `spreadlines`

Comment: @daleif Thanks, modified per your advise

Comment: What is going on with the letters in the fraction in the exponent? Looks like they overlap with the bar.

Comment: @mickep I don't think the image is made from the code posted. [I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ5rs.png)