# Text gets out beyond the table

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I use WinEdit and try to make a table. The problem is that I can not move the text in a multirow to the second line. There are the packages I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{russ}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathenv}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\ifpdf
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

% And there is a table (I left the text, which is not important, in Russian, 
% if you don't mind).

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{3cm}|p{5cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Преобразователь}& Электрооптический  &n оптический\\
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\quad} & коэффициент & фазовый \\
  \hline
  \multirow{3}{2cm}{\begin{sideways} nonlinear-crystal types \end{sideways}}& ZnTe & $r_{41}$=4.04 & 2 \\
  \cline{2-4}
  &GaP & $r_{41}$= 0.97& 4 \\
  \cline{2-4}
 &GaSe &$r_{41}$=14 & 0.7\\
  \cline{2-4}
 &GaAs&$r_{41}$=1.5& 2\\
  \cline{2-4}
 &CdTe & $r_{41}$=4.5&  \\
  \cline{2-4}
 &CdSe & $r_{41}$=18& \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Параметры генераторов ТГц импульсов}
\label{5}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

So, the turned phrase "nonlinear-crystal types" gets out beyond the table and I should move the word "types" to the second line of the column. I tried to use the command `\tabularnewline`, but it didn't work for me, maybe because I use it in a wrong way. Can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative suggestion:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{multirow,graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{multirow,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering % as opposed to using \begin{center}...\end{center}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% Widen rows of table
  \begin{tabular}{|l|p{3cm}|p{5cm}|p{3cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Some Russian} & Some more Russian & Russian again \\
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\quad} & Mini-Russian & More Russian \\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4\normalbaselineskip}{nonlinear-crystal types}}}& ZnTe & $r_{41}=4.04$ & 2 \\
    \cline{2-4}
    & GaP & $r_{41}=0.97$& 4 \\
    \cline{2-4}
    & GaSe & $r_{41}=14$ & 0.7\\
    \cline{2-4}
    & GaAs & $r_{41}=1.5$ & 2\\
    \cline{2-4}
    & CdTe & $r_{41}=4.5$ & \\
    \cline{2-4}
    & CdSe & $r_{41}=18$ & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Russian and more Russian}\label{awesome_table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Some changes include:

- Using `\rotatebox` from [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) (loaded without the `pdftex` option, since it'll figure out the required mode by itself), rather than `sideways` from [`rotating`](http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating);
- Spread out the contents of the table using a modified `\arraystretch`. See [Column padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764);
- Contained the breakable "sideways text" to `4\normalbaselineskip`. That is just short of `3*\arraystretch*\normalbaselineskip`;
- Used a `l`-column for the first column, and specified the width of the `\multirow` argument as natural (or `*`).
- Maintained math mode across the relation within the second column to provide appropriate spacing around the symbols. Perhaps, as reference, see [What is the difference between `\mathbin` vs. `\mathrel`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38982/5764)