# Correctly typesetting a relation

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, math-operators

I'm trying to typeset a relation. The following should read "< equals {...}", just in the same sense as one would use "x = {...}".

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$< = \{(x, y), (y, z)\}$
\end{document}
```

However, the spacing seems to be off: there is too little spacing left of the `=`:

[image]

Now, I could play around with `\,` and its friends to try to get the spacing right, but I guess there has to be some clear way that does not involve explicitly modifying the space. I read something along the lines of `$<{} = \{...\}$` somewhere, but that results in the space being too wide.

I guess this has been answered here before, but I couldn't find anything...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\mathord` before the `<` to indicate that it is a symbol.

```
$\mathord< = \{(x, y), (y, z)\}$
```

For more information, see the quote in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38984/24113).

Comment: Thanks, your answer works just as well -- sometimes it would really be nice if one could accept two answers here :).

Comment: @rainer This one is the correct answer; Jagath's one has better explanations of what's going on, though. No space is inserted between consecutive relation symbols, which are treated like a single one.

Comment: just putting braces around the symbol -- `{<}` -- will have the effect of making it a `\mathord` without specifying that explicitly.  this was pointed out in a comment on another answer, but i thought it useful to put the information closer to an answer with a good explanation,

Answer (score 3):

The symbols `<` and `=` are both relational operators. You can see their definition in `fontmath.ltx` as given below:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{=}{\mathrel}{operators}{"3D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{<}{\mathrel}{letters}{"3C}
```

They are declared as `\mathrel` (relational operators). My understanding is that, if they came adjacent, then the space will be closed up. To make `<` behave like a normal character, it should be treated as `\mathalpha`. So:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\mathalpha{<} = \{(x, y), (y, z)\}$
\end{document}
```

In the above example, you will get space between `<` and `=` symbols.

Comment: The diagnosis is correct, but the cure is wrong: `\mathalpha` is not the correct command, which is `\mathord` (or just a pair of braces around `<`).

Comment: @egreg: I thought of considering < as math alphabet.

Comment: The normal definition of `\mathalpha` is `\relax`; it's actually simply a place holder. Your code works because of the braces around `<`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to simply add a thick space `\;` after `<`. See the comparison with Jagath and ChrisS' answers:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, but I was trying to avoid fiddling around with explicit spacing to get what LaTeX deems correct instead of what looks nice to me.

Comment: Adding `\;` would still leave `<` considered as a binary relation symbol; if it comes first in a formula, no problem, but if it's not the first object …

Comment: You type the least stuff using `\;`, that's my point :)