# Can I use a written out logical connective, rather than a symbol?

Tags: math-mode, logic

My professor uses these really nice, written out, `AND` and `IMPLIES`, etc., symbols and I can't seem to figure out or find how he does it.

I would love to use them, rather than `\wedge` or `\land`.

Is it even possible, or did he probably create them himself (or have someone do it for him)?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is just straight-forward text, using a small-caps font:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx
\newcommand{\prob}[1]{P(#1)}
\newcommand{\AND}{\mathbin{\textsc{and}}}
\newcommand{\IMPLIES}{\mathrel{\textsc{implies}}}
\begin{document}
\[
  [\prob{r} \AND \prob{s}] \IMPLIES \prob{\mathbf{c}(r,s)}
\]
\end{document}
```

For spacing purposes, define these as macros using the appropriate `\mathrel` and/or `\mathbin`. See [What is the difference between `\mathbin` vs. `\mathrel`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38982/5764)