# Is there a logic symbol for counterfactuals

Tags: math-mode, symbols, arrows

I am looking for a symbol that looks like: []-->

So far I came up with $\Box\rightarrow$. The problem with this is, that the arrow is too far away from the box:

[image]

How could I achieve this so that the box is not so far away from the arrow?

**Update:
Solution below.**

Additionally I also needed a might counterfactual:

```
\newcommand{\counterfactualmight}{\ensuremath{%
\mathord{\Diamond}\kern-1.5pt
\raise0.5pt\hbox{$\mathord{\rightarrow}$}}}
```

[image]

**Update 2:
Better Solution** 
From
http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive

```
%..
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
%..
\begin{enumerate}
 \item A conditional: X $\rightarrow$ Y
 \item A strict conditional: X $\strictif$ Y
 \item A would-counterfactual conditional: X $\boxright$ Y
 \item A might-counterfactual conditional: X $\Diamondright$ Y
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: You might find this useful in relation to Mico's answer below. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38982/what-is-the-difference-between-mathbin-vs-mathrel

Comment: I'm glad that the basic method for the `\counterfactual`  macro also works for your `\mightcounterfactual` symbol. :-)

Comment: i know that some very similar symbols were added to unicode, so try the stix or xits fonts.  (i am not able to check these from my present location, sorry.)

Comment: Careful, \usepackage{txfonts} and \usepackage{pxfonts} changes your whole document font to a quite ugly one (to the latter one, i.e. this case pxfonts, so putting two fonts has no additional effect anyways). Since both fonts look significantly worse than the default font this is not a good solution for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A combination of `\kern`, `\raise`, `\hbox`, and `\mathord` (the final one to change the status of `\rightarrow` to "ordinary") should do the trick of aligning `\Box` and `\rightarrow`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\counterfactual}{\ensuremath{%
  \Box\kern-1.5pt
  \raise1pt\hbox{$\mathord{\rightarrow}$}}}
\begin{document}
$\Box\rightarrow$ vs.\ \counterfactual
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: I don't know if you intend to use the `\counterfactual` macro in text or math mode. (That was also, by the way, why I used `\ensuremath` to encase the macro's contents.) If you intend to use it in math mode, it may be a good idea to give it "mathrel" (relational operator) status, e.g., by defining it as

```
\newcommand{\counterfactual}{\ensuremath{%
  \mathrel{\Box\kern-1.5pt\raise1pt\hbox{$\mathord{\rightarrow}$}}}}
```

That way, the spacing in expressions such as $A \counterfactual B$ will be correct without need for further fiddling.

Comment: Could you maybe add something about `\mathrel` here?  The spacing in `$P \mathrel{\counterfactual} Q$` is (closer to) that of `$P \rightarrow Q$` than that of `$P \counterfactual Q$` is.

Comment: @DanielHarbour - Thanks for this. I've inserted an addendum to address the use of giving the new macro "mathrel" status if it's going to be used in math mode.

Answer (score 12):

There's no need to guess or measure things, other than the amount of back up. The arrow should be at the same height as plain arrows. So we can use the fact that `\mathop` applied to a single object centers it with respect to the math axis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\counterfactual}{%
  \mathrel{\mathop\Box}\mathrel{\mkern-2.5mu}\rightarrow
}
\newcommand{\mightcounterfactual}{%
  \mathrel{\mathop\Diamond}\mathrel{\mkern-2.8mu}\rightarrow
}

\begin{document}
$A\counterfactual B$

$A\mightcounterfactual B$

$\counterfactual_{\counterfactual}
 \mightcounterfactual_{\mightcounterfactual}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we use a smaller box instead?