# LaTeX symbol for "\leftrightarrow" with "\triangleq"

Tags: symbols

In LaTeX, does it exist any symbol for

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two possible alternatives.  In both cases (`\symA` and `\symB`), I use both a left and right arrow joined in order to get a wider arrow.  The `\mkern` can be increased negatively, if you want the width narrower.  The `\symA` uses the `\triangleq` component from `amssymb`, but the vertical gap can be controlled with the optional argument to `\stackon`.  The `\symB` does not require `amssymb`, but tries to mimic the tapered equal sign you showed in your figure, by using stacked `\rule`s.  Again, the vertical spacings are adjustable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\def\symA{\mathrel{\stackon[-0.8pt]{\leftarrow\mkern-6mu\rightarrow}%
  {\scriptstyle\triangleq}}}
\def\symB{\mathrel{\stackon[.7pt]{\leftarrow\mkern-6mu\rightarrow}%
  {\setstackgap{S}{0pt}\Shortstack{%
  \scriptscriptstyle\triangle\\\rule[.8pt]{6pt}{0.25pt}\\\rule{8pt}{.25pt}}}}}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
$A \symA B \symB C$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There is no ready made symbol per se, but you can definitely create a new one.

Simply define a new macro using either `\mathbin` or `\mathrel`. I think that you will need the later one, since an arrow usually shows a relation.

Please see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38982/what-is-the-difference-between-mathbin-vs-mathrel) two understand the subtle differences between the two solutions.

You use the [`\overset`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Above_and_below) command to stack up your operators.

---

Anyway here is your solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\leftrightarrowtriangleqbin}{\mathbin{\overset\triangleq\leftrightarrow}}

\newcommand{\leftrightarrowtriangleqrel}{\mathrel{\overset\triangleq\leftrightarrow}}


\begin{document}

$S \leftrightarrowtriangleqbin T$

$S \leftrightarrowtriangleqrel T$

\end{document}
```

---

And here is a sample output.

[image]

See the subtle spacing difference between the two?

---

Actually, for the second one  `\mathrel` around the construction is redundant.
As pointed out by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) below, `\overset` will keep the *binary relation* nature of its second argument.

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator`? Just a new command with `\mathrel` enclosing the code…

Comment: @Manuel Yes, may be. Depends on the context the symbols will be used.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `\DeclareMathOperator` which is not suited for this situation. By the way, an arrow usually shows a relation. Like (almost?) all the arrows defined in Latex, I would use `\newcommand\leftrightarrowtriangleq{\mathrel{\overset\triangleq\leftrightarrow}}`.

Comment: @Manuel I get your point and understand the mistake. Please post your solution for the OP. I am going to delete mine.

Comment: You can edit your answer if you think my comment is right. It was written as a suggestion to *your* answer, **not** as an answer to the *original question*.

Comment: @Manuel Okay, I will

Comment: @Manuel `\overset{\triangleeq}{\leftrightarrow}` is sufficient, because `\overset` will keep the "binary relation" nature of its second argument. So `\mathrel` around the construction is redundant.

Comment: Posted updated answer.

Comment: @egreg Great. I didn't remember that. That's the way to go.