# LaTeX symbol for “\rightarrow” with “\triangleq” und “\leftarrow” with “\triangleq”

Tags: symbols, amssymb

How can I create those two symbols in LaTeX?

[image]

I am reading my [old post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151670/latex-symbol-for-leftrightarrow-with-triangleq) but I can´t, I would do as like as Steven B. Segletes has answered

Comment: What's the problem with `\xrightarrow{\triangleeq}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply replace `leftright` in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151672/78282) by `left` and `right`, respectively (you should preferably use mathrel, thanks @egreg):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\leftrightarrowtriangleqbin}{\mathbin{\overset\triangleq\leftrightarrow}}
\newcommand{\leftrightarrowtriangleqrel}{\mathrel{\overset\triangleq\leftrightarrow}}

\newcommand{\rightarrowtriangleqbin}{\mathbin{\overset\triangleq\rightarrow}}
\newcommand{\rightarrowtriangleqrel}{\mathrel{\overset\triangleq\rightarrow}}

\begin{document}
$S \leftrightarrowtriangleqbin T$\\
$S \leftrightarrowtriangleqrel T$\\
$S \rightarrowtriangleqbin T$\\
$S \rightarrowtriangleqrel T$
\end{document}
```

EDIT: since you asked for an adaption of the [other solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151723/78282) (which was not the accepted answer)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\def\symA{\mathrel{\stackon[-0.8pt]{\longrightarrow}%
  {\scriptstyle\triangleq}}}
\def\symB{\mathrel{\stackon[.7pt]{\longrightarrow}%
  {\setstackgap{S}{0pt}\Shortstack{%
  \scriptscriptstyle\triangle\\\rule[.8pt]{6pt}{0.25pt}\\\rule{8pt}{.25pt}}}}}
\def\symC{\mathrel{\stackon[-0.8pt]{\longleftarrow}%
        {\scriptstyle\triangleq}}}
\def\symD{\mathrel{\stackon[.7pt]{\longleftarrow}%
        {\setstackgap{S}{0pt}\Shortstack{%
                \scriptscriptstyle\triangle\\\rule[.8pt]{6pt}{0.25pt}\\\rule{8pt}{.25pt}}}}}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
$A \symA B \symB C \symC D \symD E$
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `\mathrel`, not `\mathbin`