# How to draw "separating implication" symbol in Separation Logic

Tags: symbols

I want to draw a "separating implication" symbol by using Latex.

This is an operator in Separation Logic and it looks like below:

[image]

[image]

It should be a minus symbol (`-`) combining with an asterisk (`*`), but how to remove completely space between them?

I try `\mathrel{{-}{*}}` but it does not work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 10):

Is this okay?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\sepimp{\mathrel{-\mkern-6mu*}}
\begin{document}
$P\sepimp Q$
$\scriptstyle P\sepimp Q$
$\scriptscriptstyle P\sepimp Q$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would use `\mathbin` here as this seems to be a binary operator.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what `\mathrel` does? What's the difference between our answers, and why does yours look/work better?

Comment: @Ryan `\mathrel` makes the enclosed symbol to behave like a relation when it comes to inserting math glue. `\mathbin` does the same but makes to argument a binary operator. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38984/10995

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: The ordinary implication symbol \to is also a \mathrel, so this makes the spacing consistent.

Answer (score 3):

## Quick text version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\sep}{--\kern-.25em\raisebox{-.62ex}{*}\ }

\begin{document}
    P \sep Q
\end{document
```

> [image]

## Math mode version:

```
\newcommand{\sep}{-\kern-.6em\raisebox{-.659ex}{*}\ }
```

> [image]

Comment: I think it is meant to be a math operator.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yep, just realized that, and edited.