# A valid alternative(s) to siunitx package

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, siunitx, package-options, white-space

Although this question is very simple in the substance, I would like to ask it anyway. Visibly if I use the comma within the mathematical environment you can see a small space that I have underlined with a red horizontal line.

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[a=(3,15 \pm 0,22) \text{ cm}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Surely the space, with the use of `siunitx` package it will disappear as it is a specific package for units and decimal numbers. To remove this space I use the command to have a negative space `\!`. In fact I obtain this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[a=(3,\!15 \pm 0,\!22) \text{ cm}\]
\end{document}
```

Are there any other alternatives without the use of `siunitx` package?  Are there possible contraindications if you do not use this package?

Comment: Yes: just type $3{,}15$, for instance.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303110/avoid-space-after-thousands-separator-in-math-mode

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you very much to you and Bernard. I have upvoted all of the link. I'm not very familiar with siunitx package, but with Bernard's suggestion or your link I won't have problems with spaces either with commas or exponential notation? If there are further elements that I don't know, I'm very happy to know them. Otherwise I'll close my question with the closing of it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don’t want to use siunitx? In my eyes it is a great package for everything regarding numbers an units an it’s quite flexible while providing a simple input syntax. I.e. `\num{3e-2}` instead of `3 \cdot 10^{-3}` and with the former it is even possible to combin all exponents of 10 to a single one … and for errors you can use the short syntax `3,15(22)` and have it printed as in your example.

Comment: I do not use `siunitx` myself...however, the problem here, I think, is independent of that package, and is related to the fact that `,` is of math category `\mathpunct`.

Comment: If most of the math-mode commas in your document are decimal markers, definitely load the `icomma` package to change the default mode of commas from `math-punct` to `math-ord`. To restore the math-punct behavior of commas, just leave a space after them. E.g., change `$[0,1]$` to `$[0, 1]$` to typeset the interval with an appropriate amount of whitespace after the comma.

Comment: @Tobi Hi, My question arises because it takes a long time to write the decimal digits and units of measurement when I prepare my tests for my students using siunitx.I should study the manual :-( it's true. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Well, for me the input for `siunitx` seems much shorter, thus faster … in my editor I have a keyboard shortcut for `\num` and `\SI` so these are only on “click” away and then I just have to enter the numbers. (I wrote a blog post about this some time ago: https://tobiw.de/tbdm/siunitx but it is in German …)

Comment: @Tobi I'll use the translator even if it's in German :-):-) Thank you very much for your cooperation and I really appreciate your work which I think is the same as mine. You are very good user with LaTeX. I'm always in a hurry and I will probably use it in the future. Thank you always.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks :-)