# French decimal separator (comma) without any package

Tags: inline, moodle

For an online Moodle test I want to type numbers like `\(0,1040\)` where the decimal separator would be a comma and not a dot (à la French). How can I get rid of the space between the comma and the first decimal digit without any package?

Comment: Enclose the comma in a pair of curly brackets: `\(0{,}1040\)`. This works with (La)TeX. If Moodle does not actually use real (La)TeX as a backend to produce the output, but rather uses MathJax or something similar this may or may not work.

Comment: @moewe Merci. i will give it a try!

Comment: Related/duplicate? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303110/avoid-space-after-commas-used-as-thousands-separator-in-math-mode

Comment: Consider that the things between `\( \)` or `$ ... $` are passed directly to MathJax, so it depends more on MathJax than LaTeX... like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173530/mathjax-commas-in-digits, although I have no idea how to put that in the XML output...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want [`icomma`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/icomma) package.

It allows you to put a space after a comma only if there is the actual space there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{icomma}

\begin{document}

\( 1,25 \quad 1, 25 \quad (0,7) \quad (0, 7)  \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I wrote I am looking for a not-based-to-any-package workaround. (Moodle environment supports but the basic (La)Tex).