# Additional space with decimal numbers

Tags: math-mode, macros, amsmath, packages, icomma

I know that using this MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$s=1,0\, \text{m}$
\end{document}
```

it gives me a bad spacing between the comma and the 0. In fact the screenshot is:

[image]

But if I use the curly brackets `{,}` I have the same result with the `icomma` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$s=1{,}0\, \text{m}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{icomma}
\begin{document}
$s=1,0\,\text{m}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is `fontmath.ltx` the cause of this space?....from

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathpunct}{letters}{"3B}
```

> Are there better alternative methods than my MWEs that I have written without to use `siunitx` package?

Comment: If the main use in your document for `,` while in math mode is to denote the decimal marker, loading the `icomma` package has got to be the simplest way to achieve your formatting objective. From the package's user guide: "the comma will be typeset as a punctuation character if the next *input* character is a space; otherwise the comma is treated as a decimal separator."

Comment: @Mico I thank you immensely for your comment.

Comment: Does this question and answers provide the proper explanation for your needs? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303110/avoid-space-after-commas-used-as-thousands-separator-in-math-mode

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Very kind Steven, yes naturally it is provide the proper explanation. I use your same word. Now I closed the question as a duplicate. Thank you very much. I not remember all the question on this site :-) My best regards.