Removing space after decimal comma (while also modifying fonts for maths and text)
As many others, I'd like to remove the space introduced by commas in numbers (where comma is used as decimal separator).
As I want to use specific fonts for text and math, it seems that the usual solutions do not work, like using packages icomma or decimalcomma or textualicomma. (Only \num from siunitx solves this, but it requires to add a \num{} around all the numbers, which is not something I want to do in all my documents (really too many); apart from the fact that it makes them less easy to read).
For instance, the Ulricke Fisher's solution in this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303137/81138 unfortunately doesn't work after modifying the fonts:
\documentclass[a4paper, fleqn, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lxfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

%%% fixes in order to use lxfonts only for math
\let\savedrmdefault\rmdefault
\let\savedsfdefault\sfdefault
\let\savedttdefault\ttdefault
\let\saveditdefault\itdefault
\let\savedsldefault\sldefault
\let\savedbxdefault\bxdefault
\AtEndPreamble{% undo the nonmath settings by lxfonts
  \let\rmdefault\savedrmdefault
  \let\sfdefault\savedsfdefault
  \let\ttdefault\savedttdefault
  \let\itdefault\saveditdefault
  \let\sldefault\savedsldefault
  \let\bxdefault\savedbxdefault
  \setmainfont{Ubuntu}[NFSSFamily=fontid]%
}
%%%

\DeclareSymbolFont{mynumbers}      {TU}{fontid}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont    {mynumbers}{bold}{TU}{fontid}{bx}{n}

\AtBeginDocument{
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`9}
\DeclareMathSymbol{.}{\mathord}{mynumbers}{`.}
\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathpunct}{mynumbers}{`,}
}

\usepackage{icomma}

\begin{document}

$(a, b, c) = f(x, y) $  

$(a,b,c) = f(x,y) $ %wrong

$100,000$

\end{document}

Then I get:

If I remove this line: \DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathpunct}{mynumbers}{`,}, then it works again, but then the comma is printed with another font.
Is there a solution, or is it just too much fiddling with fonts and simply not possible?

Don't do those things \AtBeginDocument.
\documentclass[a4paper, fleqn, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lxfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{icomma}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Sans}[NFSSFamily=fontid]%

%%% fixes in order to use lxfonts only for math
\let\savedrmdefault\rmdefault
\let\savedsfdefault\sfdefault
\let\savedttdefault\ttdefault
\let\saveditdefault\itdefault
\let\savedsldefault\sldefault
\let\savedbxdefault\bxdefault
\AtEndPreamble{% undo the nonmath settings by lxfonts
  \let\rmdefault\savedrmdefault
  \let\sfdefault\savedsfdefault
  \let\ttdefault\savedttdefault
  \let\itdefault\saveditdefault
  \let\sldefault\savedsldefault
  \let\bxdefault\savedbxdefault
}
%%%

\DeclareSymbolFont{mynumbers}      {TU}{fontid}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont    {mynumbers}{bold}{TU}{fontid}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{mynumbers}{`9}
\DeclareMathSymbol{.}{\mathord}{mynumbers}{`.}
\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathpunct}{mynumbers}{`,}

\begin{document}

$(a, b, c) = f(x, y) $  

$100,000$

STANDARD COMMA: ,

LXFONTS COMMA: {\usefont{OT1}{llcmss}{m}{n},}

\end{document}

(No Ubuntu on this machine, so I replaced it just for the example).


As a side note, using decimalcomma instead of icomma handles the different cases even better: the space is removed only if it is between digits, not between letters.

I recommend to use \num from siunitx.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = FR}

\begin{document}

$f(a, b) = \num{3.14}$

\end{document}


OK, but as I said in my question, I noticed this solves the problem, but I'd like a solution that does not force me to wrap all numbers in all my documents with \num{}.
