# Extra spacing on the left of operator?

Tags: spacing, math-operators

When I have an operator (`\sin`,`\det`, or defined with `\operatorname`, `\DeclareMathOperator`) enclosed in `|...|`, it seems that there is an extra spacing on the left.

See the output of `$|\sin x|$ $\lvert \sin x|$` (there is no difference between `|` and `\rvert`):
[image]

I don't like this spacing now that I have noticed it. Is there a way to make `|\sin x|` output the same as `\lvert \sin x|` without manually editing each occurence? And similarly for other operators (and of course, without messing up other things)

This seems related to but unanswered by: [Spacing before an operatorname macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518047/spacing-before-an-operatorname-macro)

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$|\sin x|$ $\lvert \sin x|$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `|` and `\lvert` are not the same thing. So it is better to never use `|` at all. And perhaps define a `\abs` macro to use `\lvert... \rvert`. Mathtools has a nice construction to define `\abs`

Comment: A painful comment to hear, many pages into my document! But thank you for the input. I will look into mathtools @daleif

Comment: Whenever I edit manuscripts, one of the things on my agenda is that there should be no `|` left in the manuscript when I'm done. It can mean too many things so it is better to use separate macros

Comment: The grep command is a useful tool to find them. Added bonus of using DeclarePairedDelimiter is the build in scaling support

Comment: *Always* use `\lvert` and `\rvert`.

Comment: See also the final two use-case examples in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144439/5001) to the query [Why use the control sequences \bigl, \biggl, \bigr or \biggr, as I can always use \big or \bigg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19480/5001) [shameless self-citation alert!]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Typing in

```
|\sin x|
```

is a very common error and my eyes bleed every time I see it.

The problem is that `|` is treated as an ordinary symbol, which makes it handy to type `|x|`, but fails miserably when one has

```
|-x|
```

(try it) because the rule is that a binary operation symbol surrounded by ordinary ones will get `\medmuskip` space around it. Similarly, if a math operator follows an ordinary symbol, a thin space will be inserted, which is good for

```
2\sin x
```

where we don't want the “2” to be attached to the “s”. But the rule applies to `|\sin x|` as well. No space is inserted between `x` and `|`, because they're two ordinary symbols.

A way out would be to type

```
|{\sin x}|
```

or, better,

```
\mathopen|\sin x|
```

because no space is inserted between an **Open** atom and an **Op** atom.

In view of this deficiency, `amsmath` defines two new kinds of delimiters, namely `\lvert` and `\rvert`, in a way that's equivalent to doing `\mathopen|` and `\mathclose|` respectively (but not really so, in order to allow having `\bigl\lvert`, for instance.

Actually, doing `\bigl\lvert` is the same as `\bigl|`, because `\bigl` will give its following symbol the role of an **Open** atom. Similarly for `\bigr\rvert` and `\bigr|`.

So, no, there's not much you can do once your typescript has `|\sin x|`. You cannot redefine `|` to become an **Open** atom, because this would disrupt the instances in which it is used where a **Close** atom would be (the second one in `|\sin x|`).

I've trained myself to type in `\lvert...\rvert` every time.

You might also use `mathtools` and do

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\abs}{|}{|}
```

so

```
\abs{\sin x}
```

would do the right thing.