# Spacing after \mathinner

Tags: spacing

This is my first post here, so I hope I do it well (I am French).

I don't understand the spacing after \mathinner.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}    
  $\mathinner{}!$

  $\mathinner{}{!}$  
\end{document}
```

The spacing before `!` is not the same.

I thought `!` was of type `\mathord` so typing `{!}` shouldn't change the spacing but it does: there is a `\thinmuskip` in the second line (which is correct between `\mathinner` and `\mathord`) but not in the first line and I don't get it.
Why is `!` not of type `\mathord` in the first line? And which type is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

`!` is `\mathclose` not `\mathord` alledgedly to improve the spacing in its conventional use as factorial. However the only case where this affects the space before the ! is with `\mathinner` (`\left\right`) where usually you can get the better spacing simply by not using `\left\right` as shown in the third line here. However the second line shows the spacing that you would get with `\mathord`, with an unwanted space before the !.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$ \left(1+2\right)! + 9! $

$ \left(1+2\right){!} + 9{!} $

$ (1+2){!} + 9{!} $


\end{document}
```

LaTeX defines ! by

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{!}{\mathclose}{operators}{"21}
```

Comment: Thank you David (and campa). Is there a command to know the type of an atom?

Comment: I sometimes wonder: Since all `\mathinner` really seems to do is distort the spacing, should we consider it a historical mistake in TeX, or are there any real benefits?

Comment: @Didier You can use `\showthe\numexpr \mathcode\`! / 4096\relax`.

Comment: @Gaussler I give a full list of all the "benefits" of `\mathinner` here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173740/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle And are any of those “benefits” actually benefits? If not, doesn’t that confirm my point?

Comment: Sorry there are no benefits at all. Unfortunately it's the only way to get stretch brackets

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Exactly. This seems to be another example of a design choice made by Knuth that actually kinda ought to be changed (possibly by adding new primitives that are alternatives to `\left...\right`).

Comment: @Gaussler luatex

Comment: @Gaussler It is certainly an historical mistake to call it `ma thinner`.  Most women, especially mothers, don't want to hear of it.  I certainly avoid discussing the issue of `\mathinner` with my wife.

Comment: @frougon It doesn’t do anything

Comment: @Didier `\showthe` will stop as if for an error and show the number.

Comment: @Didier It does. You may replace `\showthe` with `\the` to obtain the result in the DVI or PDF output, but you'd be better off learning how to read TeX's messages.

Comment: @Didier Actually, because the division inside `\numexpr` *rounds* to the nearest integer (rather than truncates), one should use this instead: `\showthe\numexpr (\mathcode\`! -"800) / "1000\relax`. Without this, the result would be (class number + 1) in case the family number in the `\mathcode` were greater than or equal to 8.

Comment: Thank you frougon.

Comment: @frougon I guess I do it wrong because here is what I get in the log file:

> 5. <recently read> \relax

l.4 ...e\numexpr (\mathcode! -"800) / "1000\relax`

Comment: @Didier `5` is correct: this is the class number corresponding to a *Closing* atom as produced by `\mathclose`—see the table p. 154 of the TeXbook, which is reproduced [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38984/73317).

Comment: @frougon Thanks. I didn’t understand what meant this 5. Now, I will know. Thank you again