# How to typeset the symbol “^” (caret/circumflex/hat)

Tags: symbols

I need to display the symbol '^'

```
d <- dist(fascores, method = "euclidean")^2
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Answers from [How to look up a symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21/16595) are valid in this case. However, there are more options for circumflex than for most symbols ;)

Comment: Special case of [symbols - Escape character in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34580/escape-character-in-latex)

Answer (score 418, accepted):

[You can use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21/16595)

- in text-mode (needs `\textrm` or similar in math-mode)

  - `\textasciicircum` or
  - `\^{}`,
- in math-mode

  - `\hat{}` (only this produces a circumflex),
  - `\widehat{}`, or
  - `\wedge` (∧).
- in a verb-like manner

  - `\string^`,
  - `` \char`\^ ``,
  - `\verb!^!`:

    ```
    \verb!d <- dist(fascores, method = "euclidean")^2!
    ```

### Overview

#### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{upquote}% getting the right grave ` (and not ‘)!
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
    Input                   &       Text       &                 Math                  \\ \hline
    \verb|\string^|         &     \string^     &              $\string^$               \\
    \verb|\char`\^|         &     \char`\^     &              $\char`\^$               \\
    \verb|\verb!^!|         &     \verb!^!     &              $\verb!^!$               \\ \hline
    \verb|\textasciicircum| & \textasciicircum &                  ---                  \\
    \verb|\^{}|             & \^{} (e.g. \^a)  &                  ---                  \\ \hline
    \verb|\hat{}|           &       ---        &       $\hat{}$ (e.g. $\hat a$)        \\
    \verb|\wedge|           &       ---        &      $\wedge$ (e.g. $a\wedge b$)      \\
    \verb|\widehat{}|       &       ---        & $\widehat{\ }$ (e.g. $\widehat{abc}$) \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: As for me, in math-mode the best appearance has sequence `^\wedge`. Other variants is mostly to small.

Comment: I have accented letters, but not the symbols ^ and ` on my keyboard. Is there an easy way to input them without switching keyboard (or copy-pasting the symbols from wikipedia)?

Comment: we aslo have $\land$= \land in math mode

Comment: What is the documentclass `standalone`?

Answer (score 12):

You could also try
`\textsuperscript{$\wedge$}`
which yields:

[image]

To put this into context, `(\textsuperscript{$\wedge$}N225),` will yield:

[image]

Comment: Or, simply, `$^\wedge$`

Comment: @Dinei `$^\wedge$` does not make it superscript

Answer (score 2):

For those of you trying to do the `^^` smiley, here is a comparison of various methods (the first is `\textsuperscript`, the second is `\^`, the third is a scaled version of `\wedge` in superscript, and the last one is the second solution stretched on the y axis, with some fine tuning to have a better spacing: therefore it may need some tuning if you use different fonts):

[image]

```
Compare
\textasciicircum{}\textasciicircum{}
with
\^{}\^{}
or
\scalebox{.8}{\textsuperscript{$\wedge\wedge$}}
or the configurable % change the value in raisebox and in kern to change the spacing and the optional argument of scalebox to change the x/y ratio.
\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{\raisebox{-1.7ex}{\scalebox{1}[2]{\^{}\kern-.05em\^{}}}}.
```