# How do I write ^ as text in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, text-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)
>   [How to typset the symbol “^” (caret/circumflex)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77646/how-to-typset-the-symbol-caret-circumflex)

I would like to produce ^^ as text in my document.

The symbol is refered to as *94 (0x5E) = ^* in the ASCII table.

Comment: For your particular question see: [How to typeset the symbol "^" (caret/circumflex)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77646/2693). On how to look up symbols generally, see [How to look up a symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/2693).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 7):

Try this: `\^{}`.

More symbols see in the pdf file [symbols-a4.pdf](http://mirror.neu.edu.cn/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx Since this is a duplicate of various questions on the site (linked in my comment to the question) it's preferable to close the question as a duplicate.  See [Duplicates and closing questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/971/2693) for some discussion.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two options that come immediately to mind: `\verb=^=` and `\^`.  The first will not work inside another command and the second is actually an accent so should be typeset as `\^{}` (if you only want the caret).

It might be useful to know how you intend to use the symbol.  For example, if you want to use is as a binary operation in mathematics you could cobble together something like

```
\DeclareMathOperator\caret{\raisebox{1ex}{$\scriptstyle\wedge$}}
```

in your preamble.

Comment: once `\DeclareMathOperator\caret{\raisebox{1ex}{$\scriptstyle\wedge$}}` is declared in your preamble, how would one use this `^` in their text?