# How to print out the ^ sign?

Tags: symbols, superscripts

How to write "y^2" in latex ? I need that hook in mathmode. The error says to put the expression within $...$.

Comment: @Suman: Beware, all methods provide different output: `% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
y\textasciicircum2
\verb!y^2!
$y\string^2$
\end{document}
`

Comment: The main question is: *why* do you want to print the `^` and not use the standard exponent?

Comment: @egreg - "[Ours is] not to reason why" (Alfred Lord Tennyson, The Charge of the Light Brigade, 1855). :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are several methods for showing the `^` character -- in math mode, text mode, and "verbatim" ("monospaced font") mode. (The third text mode variant and the verbatim variant courtesy of cmhughes and Johannes_B...)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$y\string^2$ --- math mode

y\string^2 --- text mode, variant 1 (same as math mode)

y\^{}2  --- text mode, variant 2

y\textasciicircum 2 --- text mode, variant 3

\verb|y^2| --- monospaced (``verbatim'') font mode
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\hat{}`?.......

Comment: @HenriMenke - Not really. For sure, the output of `$y\hat{}2$` is downright awful.

Comment: `$y\hat{~}2$`..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little experiment of what you are asking --

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\begin{document}

$y\string^2$ \\
y\string^2 \\
y\^{}2 \\
y\textasciicircum2\\
\verb!y^2!\\
y\textsuperscript{\^{}}2 \\
$y \mathbin{\char`\^} 2$ \\
$y ^\wedge 2$\\
$y^\bigwedge 2$\\

% requires `tipa` package
y {\textturnv} 2 \\

% one bad idea: use \Lambda
$y ^\Lambda 2$ \\

% update #1: requires `upgreek` package
$y ^\Uplambda 2$
\end{document}
```

***UPDATE***

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77646/how-to-typset-the-symbol-caret-circumflex-hat), you may like to have a look.