# How can I format `^' better?

Tags: formatting

I met a format problem: when I use

```
`$\hat{}$'
```

to present ‘^’, I found that the output format is very crowded. I mean the three character

" ‘ ", " ^ ", and " ’ " are printed in an excessively compact form. Anyone can give me a hint to format it better. What I want is something like ‘^’.

Comment: Related: [Q77646](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77646)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add some spacing, a thin space could be what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

We use `$\,\hat{}\,$' over a symbol to denote

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ egreg, Thanks for your useful hint. I have chosen `\>` as the space in this case.

Answer (score 5):

A solution which doesn't require extra spacing: `\^{}`. (`\textasciicircum` works too.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
We use `\^{}' over a symbol to denote
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note this assumes the text font matches the math font.

Comment: @AndrewSwann - the OP wasn't sufficiently specific about the use case, but I suspect it's more appropriate to use text mode than math mode. Maybe the OP will weigh in and clarify the intended use.