# TeXworks compilation error when using ^ as a plain text

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, miktex, texworks

In my `TeXworks` (MikTeX 2.9) editor, the following file compiles correctly. But when I change `sin-1(x)` to `sin^-1(x)` the following error occurs. I thought TeXworks would treat sin^-1(x) just as a plain text if not inside `amsmath` delimiters `$..$, \(...\)` etc.:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.8 Ignore sin^
               -1(x) for typesetting
?
```

**.text File:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

This \(a^{4}\) is a test.
Ignore sin-1(x) for typesetting
Another \(a_3\) test.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\^{}`, also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77646/how-to-typset-the-symbol-caret-circumflex-hat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with TeXworks, MikTeX, or Ams-TeX; the LaTeX compiler itself is throwing this error at you.

The issue is that LaTeX restricts the usage of some symbols that have a special meaning to the interpreter. For example, because `%` signals the beginning of a comment, if you want a percent sign in your document, you have to write it as `\%`. Similarly, you will also need to escape `\`, `#`, `$`, `^`, `&`, `~`, `_`, `{`, and `}` in text mode, because these all have special meanings.

Specifically, `^` means a superscript in math mode, so `$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$` is OK, but `the 5^{th} symphony` will generate the same error you have, since `^` isn't allowed in textmode without being escaped.

To solve this problem, you have a couple options, depending on context and what you want it to look like.

1. You can write `sin\^{-1}(x)` and keep everything in text mode.
2. You can use `\textsuperscript` to get a superscript in text mode: `sin\textsuperscript{-1}(x)`.
3. You can put everything in math mode, where it works without issue: `$\sin^{-1}(x)$`. (Writing `\sin` instead of `sin` typesets it upright, which looks better.)
4. If you want it written in monospace, use `\verb+sin^-1(x)+`.

Here's how each of these options looks in the final document. I personally prefer option 3.

[image]

Comment: Is `\, #, $, ^, &, ~, _, {, and }` a complete list of special characters in LaTeX that one need to escape in text mode? If not, could some please provide a link to such a list? Following [post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34586/22810) makes me to believe that this may indeed be the complete list.

Comment: @nam: my reference was the [Not So Short Guide to LaTeX](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf), §1.3.2 (p. 5).