# How to disable super or subscripting in text mode

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

Writing a report with some part numbers, for example "partname_123". I want to write the underline as a underline and not as sub-scripting. How do I disable the super/sub-scripting in a regular text? is there a general command I can use or just a command for the specific word, like: `\ignore-super-sub-scripting{partname_123}`

-Using a sharelatex template that I found: Business report (version 1)

Comment: `partname\_123`

Comment: For the superscript part, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77646/how-to-typset-the-symbol-caret-circumflex-hat  If you want to see different possibilities to "prettify" the underscore, you can also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/underscores-in-words-text

Comment: One *can* (but probably shouldn't) try to redefine the meaning of underscores in text mode and revert to its regular meaning in math mode.  Above my pay grade.

Answer (score 1):

I take my comment back.  There's a package for this!

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{underscore}


\begin{document}
    This_is_probably_not a_good_idea.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should move this answer to the question linked as duplicate.

Comment: I have added it there, but I don't think it's a duplicate.  The question there relates to the look of the underscore, not the procedure for obtaining it.

Comment: It says clearly how to get the underscore. *Every* basic guide explains that the underscore can be obtained by doing `\_` and that `_` is, by default, a special character.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity: this question is about how to get the underscore when entered as _ to produce an underscore.  The other question is about how to make the underscore look prettier.

Comment: I don't agree: the OP simply didn't know how to produce the underscore. It's a well known newbie problem.

Comment: Ok, you're probably right in that's what s/he intends to ask, but that's not what the question says.