# How to use "^" above y in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, overset

I was trying to put `^` above `y`, the follow ways didn't work:

1. `$\overset{^}{y}`
2. `$^y$`
3. `$y^{^}$`

I wanted something like overset, I would be glad if some one could help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se! Maybe your question has already been answered here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77647/172164 (`\hat{y}` or `\widehat{y}`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for help me! I didn't find it before!