# How to type the circled power symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

When working with tropical mathematics, I can type `$\oplus$` for the tropical plus,  `$\odot$` for the tropical multiplication. The symbol for the tropical power is the power sign inside a circle, but I can not center the power sign at the center of the outer circle using solution in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers) and [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77646/how-to-typeset-the-symbol-caret-circumflex-hat).

How to type the symbol for the tropical power?

I expect as in the following formular (page 7 in [here](http://www.mathenjeans.fr/sites/default/files/sujets/tropical_geometry_-_casagrande.pdf))

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage{stmaryrd}` and `\owedge`. Table 52 in the Comprehensive list.

Comment: @egreg It works as expected. Thank you!